# What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql, join

I'm writing a LINQ to SQL statement, and I'm after the standard syntax for a normal inner join with an `ON` clause in C#.

How do you represent the following in LINQ to SQL:

```
select DealerContact.*
from Dealer 
inner join DealerContact on Dealer.DealerID = DealerContact.DealerID
```

Comment: If you have a foreign key between the tables, you should look Kirk Broadhurst's answer below.

Comment: @ANeves It's far from standard practice to use plural table names, both singular and plural are perfectly acceptable - I just switched from plural to singular myself to match object names - here the top answer agrees singular is more consistent (many pluralisations are weird or non existent - eg '1 sheep, 8 sheep': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names/14929526

Comment: @niico this is not the place to discuss that, I guess... but Microsoft Entity Framework [pluralizes the table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425027/entity-framework-code-first-naming-conventions-back-to-plural-table-names), Ruby on Rails' ORM [pluralizes the tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)... is that close enough to standard-practice for you? :) Counter-argument: NHibernate [seems to not pluralize tables](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#components).

Comment: Indeed - some people do it one way - some do it another way. There is no standard practice. Personally I think singular has way more benefits.

Answer (score 616, accepted):

It goes something like:

```
from t1 in db.Table1
join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}
```

It would be nice to have sensible names and fields for your tables for a better example. :)

**Update**

I think for your query this might be more appropriate:

```
var dealercontacts = from contact in DealerContact
                     join dealer in Dealer on contact.DealerId equals dealer.ID
                     select contact;
```

Since you are looking for the contacts, not the dealers.

Comment: thank you, from now on i will use **sensible names** as best practise which makes sense in linq , instead of `from c or from t1`

Comment: I've used linq joins like many times in the past but I ran into an issue that I hadn't seen before, since the error you see in VS is not entirely clear:
When you write the ON statement you must reference the FROM table first. You can say `on t1.field equals t2.field` but you cannot write `on t2.field equals t1.field` as the compiler won't understand what t2 is referring to in that case.

Answer (score 250):

And because I prefer the expression chain syntax, here is how you do it with that:

```
var dealerContracts = DealerContact.Join(Dealer, 
                                 contact => contact.DealerId,
                                 dealer => dealer.DealerId,
                                 (contact, dealer) => contact);
```

Comment: If you need to filter or select on fields from *both* joined tables, instead of just on fields of one of the two tables (the DealerContact table in this answer's example), here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310640/12484

Answer (score 70):

To extend the expression chain syntax [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851487/12484) by Clever Human:

If you wanted to do things (like filter or select) on fields from both tables being joined together -- instead on just one of those two tables -- you could create a new object in the lambda expression of the final parameter to the Join method incorporating both of those tables, for example:

```
var dealerInfo = DealerContact.Join(Dealer, 
                              dc => dc.DealerId,
                              d => d.DealerId,
                              (dc, d) => new { DealerContact = dc, Dealer = d })
                          .Where(dc_d => dc_d.Dealer.FirstName == "Glenn" 
                              && dc_d.DealerContact.City == "Chicago")
                          .Select(dc_d => new {
                              dc_d.Dealer.DealerID,
                              dc_d.Dealer.FirstName,
                              dc_d.Dealer.LastName,
                              dc_d.DealerContact.City,
                              dc_d.DealerContact.State });
```

The interesting part is the lambda expression in line 4 of that example:

```
(dc, d) => new { DealerContact = dc, Dealer = d }
```

...where we construct a new anonymous-type object which has as properties the DealerContact and Dealer records, along with all of their fields.

We can then use fields from those records as we filter and select the results, as demonstrated by the remainder of the example, which uses `dc_d` as a name for the anonymous object we built which has both the DealerContact and Dealer records as its properties.

Comment: Joins with lambdas have awful syntax. I refuse to use it ;-)

Comment: @aristo I don't blame you at all.  I usually have to refer back to this post to remind myself of the syntax!

Comment: Some people like me prefers consistency. That's why I search for the lambda syntax specifically.

Answer (score 47):

```
var results = from c in db.Companies
              join cn in db.Countries on c.CountryID equals cn.ID
              join ct in db.Cities on c.CityID equals ct.ID
              join sect in db.Sectors on c.SectorID equals sect.ID
              where (c.CountryID == cn.ID) && (c.CityID == ct.ID) && (c.SectorID == company.SectorID) && (company.SectorID == sect.ID)
              select new { country = cn.Name, city = ct.Name, c.ID, c.Name, c.Address1, c.Address2, c.Address3, c.CountryID, c.CityID, c.Region, c.PostCode, c.Telephone, c.Website, c.SectorID, Status = (ContactStatus)c.StatusID, sector = sect.Name };


return results.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi,

Can you tell me please what is this part is about?

 Status = (ContactStatus)c.StatusID

I am interested expecially in the fragment: (ContactStatus)c.StatusID


Regards
Mariusz

Comment: @aristo - looking at the code, I'm guessing that `ContactStatus` is really an enum, and `c.StatusID` isn't really an ID, but the numeric value of the enum. If I'm right, `(ContactStatus)c.StatusID` is really just casting an integer to an enum.

Answer (score 26):

Use [Linq Join](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx) operator:

```
var q =  from d in Dealer
         join dc in DealerConact on d.DealerID equals dc.DealerID
         select dc;
```

Comment: what to do when i want columns of both d & dc ?

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Then return a class you have created like select new MyCustomer{ Id = dc.id, Id2 = d.id } Thats it!

Answer (score 26):

You create a foreign key, and LINQ-to-SQL creates navigation properties for you. Each `Dealer` will then have a collection of `DealerContacts` which you can select, filter, and manipulate.

```
from contact in dealer.DealerContacts select contact
```

or

```
context.Dealers.Select(d => d.DealerContacts)
```

If you're not using navigation properties, you're missing out one of the main benefits on LINQ-to-SQL - the part that maps the object graph.

Comment: Oh man, you saved my time, I don't need to deal with these stupid joins anymore!

Answer (score 23):

basically LINQ **join** operator provides no benefit for SQL. I.e. the following query

```
var r = from dealer in db.Dealers
   from contact in db.DealerContact
   where dealer.DealerID == contact.DealerID
   select dealerContact;
```

will result in INNER JOIN in SQL

**join** is useful for IEnumerable<> because it is more efficient:

```
from contact in db.DealerContact
```

clause would be re-executed for every **dealer**
But for IQueryable<> it is not the case. Also **join** is less flexible.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, often it is better not to join, in linq that is. When there are navigation properties a very succinct way to write your linq statement is:

```cs
from dealer in db.Dealers
from contact in dealer.DealerContacts
select new { whatever you need from dealer or contact }
```

It translates to a where clause:

```sql
SELECT <columns>
FROM Dealer, DealerContact
WHERE Dealer.DealerID = DealerContact.DealerID
```

Comment: What does a LINQ query with multiple "from" clauses (as in this example) look like in expression chain syntax?  Is it possible?

Comment: Its method syntax equivalent is `SelectMany()`.

Answer (score 6):

Inner join two tables in linq C#

```
var result = from q1 in table1
             join q2 in table2
             on q1.Customer_Id equals q2.Customer_Id
             select new { q1.Name, q1.Mobile, q2.Purchase, q2.Dates }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [LINQ joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) to perform Inner Join.

```
var employeeInfo = from emp in db.Employees
                   join dept in db.Departments
                   on emp.Eid equals dept.Eid 
                   select new
                   {
                    emp.Ename,
                    dept.Dname,
                    emp.Elocation
                   };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
     var data =(from t1 in dataContext.Table1 join 
                 t2 in dataContext.Table2 on 
                 t1.field equals t2.field 
                 orderby t1.Id select t1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
OperationDataContext odDataContext = new OperationDataContext();    
        var studentInfo = from student in odDataContext.STUDENTs
                          join course in odDataContext.COURSEs
                          on student.course_id equals course.course_id
                          select new { student.student_name, student.student_city, course.course_name, course.course_desc };
```

Where student and course tables have primary key and foreign key relationship

Answer (score 2):

try instead this,

```
var dealer = from d in Dealer
             join dc in DealerContact on d.DealerID equals dc.DealerID
             select d;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Data= (from dealer in Dealer join dealercontact in DealerContact on dealer.ID equals dealercontact.DealerID
select new{
dealer.Id,
dealercontact.ContactName

}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data=(from t in db.your tableName(t1) 
          join s in db.yourothertablename(t2) on t1.fieldname equals t2.feldname
          (where condtion)).tolist();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = (from u in db.Users join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId where u.Username == username
   select new {u.UserId, u.CustomerId, u.ClientId, u.RoleId, u.Username, u.Email, u.Password, u.Salt, u.Hint1, u.Hint2, u.Hint3, u.Locked, u.Active,c.ProfilePic}).First();
```

Write table names you want, and initialize the select to get the result of fields.

Comment: var list = (from u in db.Yourfirsttablename
                           join c in db.secondtablename on u.firsttablecommonfields equals c.secondtablecommon field
                           where u.Username == username
                           select new {u.UserId, u.CustomerId, u.ClientId, u.RoleId, u.Username, u.Email, u.Password, u.Salt, u.Hint1, u.Hint2, u.Hint3, u.Locked, u.Active,c.ProfilePic}).First();

Answer (score 1):

from d1 in DealerContrac join d2 in DealerContrac on d1.dealearid equals d2.dealerid select new {dealercontract.*}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer adds nothing to the already existing answers.

Answer (score -6):

One Best example

Table Names :  `TBL_Emp` and `TBL_Dep`

```
var result = from emp in TBL_Emp join dep in TBL_Dep on emp.id=dep.id
select new
{
 emp.Name;
 emp.Address
 dep.Department_Name
}


foreach(char item in result)
 { // to do}
```