# Django model naming convention

Tags: django, django-models, naming-conventions

What is the preferred naming convention for Django model classes?

Comment: just name it so you know what the model stands for

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Django models are just Python classes, so the Python naming conventions detailed in [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) apply.

For example:

1. Person
2. Category
3. ZipCode

If Django fails to pluralize the class name properly when creating the corresponding table, you can easily override the pluralization by setting a custom *verbose_name_plural* field in an inner META class. For example:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"
```

Comment: what plural name django will create for model name `Person`?

Comment: As per docs, I believe variable name is verbose_name_plural. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options

Comment: didn't find any proof to this in pep-8

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the idea is that the class name should be singular and should use SentenceCase with no spaces. So you'd have names like:

```
Person
TelephoneNumber
```

Then the Django admin tool knows how to pluralise them. Doesn't work so nicely for names like:

```
Category
```

which gets pluralised as Categorys, but there we go...

Apart from that, just give it a name that means something to you and succinctly sums up what the class is meant to represent.

Ben

Comment: See ghoseb's answer above about correctly pluralizing something like Categories.

Answer (score 2):

In most of programming languages, people prefer give a singular names to the objects/models because these models are also represented by tables in your database system. The minimalism is a good choice everytime to avoid some meaning conflicts in the future.

To exemplify;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841297/2643226

Answer (score 0):

In adition, when you need related objects for a Model of more than one word, you can use the _set attribute. Example:

```
class ProcessRoom(models.Model):
...
    plant = models.ForeignKey("Plant", verbose_name='planta', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, related objects will be:

```
plant = Plant.object.get(id=1)
process_rooms = plant.processroom_set.all
```