# I want to create a doctor and user database in Django. But having problem in models please see the code below

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

> This class is for the doctor info

```
class doc_info(models.Model):
    doc_name = models.TextField()
    speciality = models.TextField()
    exp = models.TextField()
    contact = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doc_name
```

> This class is for user information

```
class usr_info(models.Model):
    age = models.TextField()
    blood_group = models.TextField()
    height = models.TextField()
    weight = models.TextField()

    vision = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()
    note = models.TextField()
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

> Here I am trying to add multiple docs to user_info

```
    recent_doc = models.ManyToManyField(doc_info)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recent_doc
```

> I am getting SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: ValueError: Cannot add "<doc_info: Dr. ABC>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default" This shows up whenever I try to add

Comment: Start by fixing class name it should start with Uppercase character, and make it in Kamel World format

Comment: When you are getting this error? Is this error occurs during `makemigrations` command?

Comment: As mentioned by @ahmedbarbouche make sure to make your class name CamelCase. And make sure to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` commands.

Comment: @ahmedbarbouche ok will do that and check and get back to you but can you tell me why camecasing? is that mandatory in Django?

Comment: @Mubasharjaved no problem is there in makemigrations and migrate it is coming when I try to run query and in that when I try to add doc_name in usr_info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385895/django-model-naming-convention