# How to get last six month report django (even in between months not having entry)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I wanted to get last six months of employee count by checking joining_date field

```
class Employee(models.Model):
employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
joining_Date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Example:

```
July : 12,
June : 10,
May : 8,
April : 16,
March : 13,
February : 10,
```

I got an answer for that from 0svoid, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078533/how-to-get-last-six-month-data-from-date-field-django)
Its really working great! but problem is when there is no entry in particular month I want it to be 0 instead of not coming in the list.

Say for example june month not having any employee joining.

it should show like

```
July : 12,
June : 0,
May : 8,
April : 16,
March : 13,
February : 10,
```

instead of below one.

```
July : 12,
May : 8,
April : 16,
March : 13,
February : 10,
```

I want to work on many scenario(s) something like above , please suggest me any module or a way to generate reports to show in the template from the database(s)..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have information into your database, you can not count and show it.
Therefore you should create additional code:

```
from 'django.utils.dates import MONTHS

MONTHS_DICT = dict.fromkeys(MONTHS, 0)

# employees_per_month = answer from  0svoid

MONTHS_DICT.update(**employees_per_month)

print(MONTHS_DICT)
```