# Calling class/enum different than its objects - Java

Tags: java, class, enums, rename

I have I quick question, say I have this class:

```
public enum Files {
    FILE_A, FILE_B;
}
```

Now FILE_A is a "Files", but being a "File" would be more intuitive. To example, when using a foreach, I need to use something like this:

```
for (Files file : Files.values()) {

}
```

Where File would be better(in my opinion). Is there a way of calling objects of a class different than the class itself? Like calling object of the class/enum "Files" "File".
With classes I had the idea to do something like this:

```
public class A extends B {
    public static final FILE_A;
}

public class B {

}
```

Now every A is also a B, but that is not a clean way and doesn't work with enums. Is there another way?

Comment: Made me laugh: `class A extends B`. But, no, there are no aliasing options in Java, but maybe a common superinterface will do the trick.

Comment: You should learn Java basics first...

Comment: I did, I'm just curious!

Comment: Why don't you simply rename Files to File?

Comment: I don't really know what do you mean when using the verb `call`...

Comment: Curious about what? First of all, there's already a class `File` in JDK so you should not create another class with that name or with the same name of the JDK. Second: `public static final FILE_A` doesn't compile. From your last statement, I'm not sure if you want your `enum` to extend from another class.

Comment: See also this related C# question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405851/enum-naming-convention-plural

Comment: possible duplicate of [Naming of enums in Java: Singular or Plural?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755955/naming-of-enums-in-java-singular-or-plural)

Answer (score 1):

Class names should be in singular (in most cases).

Also, giving enum values a prefix isn't common in java.

Answer (score 1):

The enum class name (like most class names) is usually singular rather than plural. Take [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) as an example. Referring to instances, then, is a more grammatically natural `TimeUnit.SECONDS` rather than the awkward `TimeUnits.SECONDS`.