# MySQL: Unique constraint on multiple fields

Tags: sql, mysql, unique

I have two tables --> Variables (id, name) and Variable_Entries (id, var_id, value).

I want each variable to have a unique set of entries.  If I make the value entry unique then a different variable won't be able to have that same value which is not right.

Is there some way to make the value column unique for identical var_id's?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
alter table Variable_Entries add unique (var_id, value);
```

Now you have a unique constraint across var_id and value together.  In other words, no occurrence of var_id and value can appear more than once.

Comment: thanks, and people below too-- I couldn't find this anywhere

Comment: Is there a way to enforce this when creating the table?

Comment: you may not be wanting to know but for the sake of others,
`create table tbl_table
(
 id integer not null auto_increment,
 fname varchar(255),
        lname varchar(255),
 CONSTRAINT tbl_table PRIMARY KEY (id),
 unique (fname,lname)
)`

Comment: Does that mean that a particular value of var_id can show up more than once, but a particular combination of var_id and value can not show up more than once?

Comment: @Scorb yes. That's what it means.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create a composite [unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key):

```
ALTER TABLE variable_entries ADD UNIQUE (var_id, value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the word *composite*, made me understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique key of Variable_Entries for the combined fields var_id/value.

Also, you should always use singular words for table names (user instead of users). Never use uppercase characters in the table name, because that will cause you a NIGHTMARE over different operating systems.

Comment: I wonder why should we always use singular names for table names?

Comment: "You should always use singular words for table names" - I disagree. I always use the plural, and I know I'm not alone (ActiveRecord, for example, does the same).

Comment: CakePHP depends on plurals for table names... It's a funny comment :) Uppercase, though... I agree

Comment: Plural vs singular table names is a religious debate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names