# How to enforce unique constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a MySQL table defined:

```sql
File
--------------------------
ID int(11) PK
name varchar(100)
customerId int(11) FK
isPrimaryImage tinyint(1)
....
```

I've read here that MySQL doesn't support a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` with a `WHERE` condition. For each *customerId* we'd have only one *primaryImage = 1*.

So what else can I do to enforce this constraint?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504007/mysql-unique-constraint-on-multiple-fields

Comment: Even if MySQL supports unique constraints, you cannot use one here (assuming you'll several secondary images per customer), since you'll have several tuples with the same customerID and isPrimaryImage = 0 (but you could use NULL instead of 0 for these).

Comment: Table design is off, you can't enforce what you want with such layout.

Comment: I agree with Michael J.V. - instead of doing it your way, I'd get rid of the isPrimaryImage column and add a customerPrimaryImage table instead (having a CustomerID, a ImageID and a unique constraint on CustomerID).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`MySQL` perfectly supports unique constraints.

It does not support partial constraints/indexes, though, so you would need to mark non-primary images with a `NULL` instead of `0`.

```
ALTER TABLE file ADD CONSTRAINT ux_file_customer_primary 
UNIQUE (customerId, isPrimaryImage)
```

You can insert arbitrary number of `NULL` values into `isPrimaryImage` but only one non-null value per customer.

Comment: @quassnoi == casse-noix ??