# Inserting only once

Tags: java, mysql

I have 2 instances of a program, accessing 1 table in a database.
Table `points`

```
game    |  player1  |  player2
--------|-----------|-----------
Poker   |    5      |   
Skat    |    8      |    4
Bridge  |           |   10
```

If player1, using the first instance, wants to save his points (e.g. Poker) into the table, it has to be made sure, whether Poker is already there. If not, Poker will be inserted together with the points of player1. But if Poker was already inserted by player2, only the points of player1 should be inserted (the row should only be altered).
How can I make sure, that every sort of game is only inserted once and in this case only the points are inserted (altered)?
I think, the column `game` has to be unique.
My solution is to query the sort of game at first and check the number of rows. If there are 0 rows, insert the game and points, if there is already 1 row, only insert the points.
But is there a better/faster solution, whithout querying at first?

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your database design. If you happen to add more users it would be better to have tables for `users`, `games` and a crossreferencing table `user_game`.

Comment: I know, this is just an example. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO points (game,player1) VALUES ('Poker',5)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE player1=5;
```

For more information, see the MySQL documentation: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Is it also possible for a **combination** of entries? So that `Poker` is allowed several times, but only once for every player? The combination `game - player1` only should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Break your insert into two statements. For this to work, 'game' must be a unique column - that is, no two values can be the same.

```
INSERT INTO 'game' VALUES('Poker',null,null);
UPDATE 'game' SET player1='5' WHERE 'game'='POKER';
```

The first line won't affect anything if it's already there, because the unique constraint will prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace into syntax. Note that you can create a unique constraint for your database tables.

Read about replace into [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).
Read about unique constraint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679122/mysql-unique-constraint).

Answer (score 0):

```
 REPLACE INTO points (game,player1) VALUES ('Poker',5);
```