# Output document from collection in node.js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoDB and mongoose, i have this simple document in 'users' collection in MongoLab:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55819f00e4b0a09388237163"
    },
    "name": "john"
}
```

In my express:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://ds047***.mongolab.com:47792/heroku_16lpd***');
mongoose.model('users', {name: String});
mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
   console.log(users); => undefind
});
```

and getting undefined. could it be that my connection string is wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `mongoose.model('users'...` with `mongoose.model('user'...` - mongoose pluralizes model names.

Comment: @x-ray Are you sure, as this sounds a bit insane?

Comment: Just google "mongoose pluralization" and you will e.g. find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230953/what-are-mongoose-nodejs-pluralization-rules

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the scenario you are experiencing but I created a similar example which is working:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User', {name: String});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('connected');
  }
});

User.create({name: 'Wilson'}, function () {

  User.find(function (err, users) {
    console.log(users);  // [{_id: 558240fbbfca399053238ac7, name: 'Wilson', __v: 0}]
  });

});
```