# Data not shown after connecting to MongoDB using mongoose in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a database on mongodb named 'abode' and I am trying to make an API where I can use this data to be displayed on a web app. The file structure of the web app is like this.

[image]

**app.js**

```
const http = require('http'); //Core Module
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path'); //Core Module
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

Bhk = require('./models/bhk');
//Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/abode');

const db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/api/bhk', (req, res)=>{
    Bhk.getBHK(function(err, bhk){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.json(bhk);
    });
});
```

**bhk.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//BHK schema
const bhkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const bhk = module.exports = mongoose.model('BHK', bhkSchema);

// Get BHK
module.exports.getBHK = function(callback, limit){
    bhk.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

When I run the app it shows an empty array on my webpage. Like this 
[image]

The server starts successfully and there are no errors shown in my console as well. In the collections of my database I have a collection named - BHK. It consists of two records

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d60827fad61a75bbcb5e9"), "Name" : "2BHK" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d60b77fad61a75bbcb5ea"), "Name" : "3BHK" }
```

However no of these records are shown. I tried searching for various solutions of using a mongo db client, however I could not yet get the required result. I do not know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of surfing through the net and trial and error, I realized MongoDB has a convention for naming collections and databases.
The collection that I had named was **'BHK'**, which according to its [guidelines](http://arkusnexus.com/2016/09/12/coding-guidelines-mongodb/?nabe=5802299602763776:0&utm_referrer=https://www.google.co.in/)
and [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868323/is-there-a-convention-to-name-collection-in-mongodb) was wrong.
The collection name has to be in lower case and plural which in my case I had to rename the collection to:

> bhks