# URI design in a RESTful web api

Tags: web-services, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've never had to design a RESTful service before and I want to map out the URI routes.

Lets say there are `Foo` and `Bar` objects. A `Foo` can have multiple `Bars` associated with it but a `Bar` can be independent of any `Foos` too. Obviously since both of these types can exist independently they'll need their own URI hierarchy, like so:

```
/Foos
/Bars
```

Here's where my question comes in. Lets say I want to create a `Bar` and associate it with a `Foo`. Which of these methods would be the best way to implement this?

Method 1: a single api call that creates the `Bar` and associates it with the `Foo`.

```
POST /Foos/{FooId}/Bars
```

Method 2: a call to create the `Bar`, then a call to associated the new `Bar` with the `Foo`. Would PUT be the correct method on the associate call?

```
POST /Bars
PUT /Foos/{FooId}/Bars/{BarId}
```

Method 3: something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer Method 2, but I would seriously consider whether it would be a good idea to do Method 1 in addition.

I like Method 2 because it allows you to create your independent `Bar`, and then, if appropriate, associate it with the `Foo` (or multiple `Foo`s if desired).

Some questions that I would apply here are:

- Does it matter if a `Bar` that's *supposed* to be associated with a `Foo` is successfully created, and but is not successfully associated with that `Foo`?
- Can a `Bar` be associated with more than one `Foo`?
- Does the `Bar` know anything about the `Foo`(s) it's associated with?
- Can a `Foo` have more than one `Bar` ?

If having a floating `Bar` that *should* be associated with a `Foo` but isn't is a really bad thing, then you'll need something like Method 1 (otherwise something could happen between the 1st and 2nd call of Method 2).

I like the convention of POST to create and PUT to modify (so I'd do Method 2 like you suggest).

You might also want to check the pluralisation in your URI.  I tend to prefer singular but ... discussion here -

[REST URI convention - Singular or plural name of resource while creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845772/rest-uri-convention-singular-or-plural-name-of-resource-while-creating-it)