# Rest API chained parameters in URL

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am currently designing a REST API. I have got a `Group` Entity and an `Event` Entity. One `Event` belongs to exactly one `Group`, but one `Group` can have multiple `Events`.

`Groups` are accessed via

```
/groups/group/{groupId}
```

---

I am not sure about where to put the `Event` endpoint:

```
/groups/group/{groupId}/events/event/{eventId}
```

or just

```
/events/event/{eventId}
```

Posting new `Events` into a `Group` is easier with the upper, whereas just getting data about one `Event` is easier with the lower approach.
Which of them should I use, or should I even "mix" them? (one for `GET`, one for `POST`)

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21809963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your REST basic endpoints should be like this:

- [POST] add group  `/groups`
- [GET] get all groups `/groups`
- [GET] fetch/get a group by id `/groups/{id}
- [PUT]update/modify a group by id `/groups/{id}
- [DELETE] delete a group by id `/groups/{id}

---

- [POST] add event  `/events`
- [GET] get all events `/events`
- [GET] fetch/get a event by id `/events/{id}
- [PUT]update/modify a event by id `/events/{id}
- [DELETE] delete a event by id `/events/{id}

---

So now come on you want to fetch an event of the specific group by `id` like you tried here `/groups/group/{groupId}/events/event/{eventId}` right?

you can fetch all events of a group like this :

- `/events?group_id={groupId}` like this here you can implement.
- and the same for vice-varsa you can fetch all groups those who have the specific event by this `/groups?event_id={event_Id}`
- Now if you want to fetch specific group and specific event so you can do by `/groups/{id}?event={eventId}` that 3rd route or endpoint of Group's REST above and same for vice-varsa.