# How to design RESTful API url while resource is cascade？

Tags: api, rest

I have two resources: Device and Model, and Model is under Device

This is my current URL design:

### Device

`api.example.com/devices/{id}`

### Model

Which one is correct?

`api.example.com/device/models/{id}`

`api.example.com/devices/models/{id}`

Comment: There is no right and wrong

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845772/should-i-use-singular-or-plural-name-convention-for-rest-resources