# REST endpoints URL what is a good practise in API design

Tags: rest

I am creating an API that uploads files related to some cars for example:

I have come up with two possible endpoints of uploading the files containing car information, the data in the files will be saved to DB:

```
POST:

/api/v1/files/cars

/api/v1/uploads/cars
```

Two possible ways of downloading car data (which will be processed) from the DB slightly but will be downloaded as files:

```
GET:

/api/v1/templates/cars

/api/v1/files/cars
```

This can be a matter of taste, but im trying to gain opinions of what is better, are the resource the uploads or the files?

Comment: I think `cars/files` for files relating to ALL cars or `car/$ID/file/$FILE_ID` is better frankly. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845772/should-i-use-singular-or-plural-name-convention-for-rest-resources

Try to use URLS that can have GET and POST actions - unless you can retrieve detail on the status of an upload then `uploads` is probably not what you want,

Answer (score 0):

[REST](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, beyond the fact that they should be [uniform](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) resource identifiers.

URI identify the resources in your resource model, and part of the point of REST is to be resource model agnostic (so that we can use the same general purpose semantics to communicate with any resource model).

Deciding whether sending information to the server should use the same resources (and therefore the same resource identifiers) as reading information from the server is part of the problem of designing a resource model that fits your needs.

One reason that you might want to use the same resource for both: general purpose HTTP components can do useful [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons) if they know that the same resource is involved.

But it's a trade off - how important is cache invalidation, how important are the benefits of other design alternatives, etc.