# appropriate model name and db table plural naming convention

Tags: database, model, naming-conventions

I am using django and making a system similar to job portal or linkedin or a community of professionals. So there are 2 tables/models other than auth_users, one is company while I am confuse about other model name. Should I name it Professional or Person? If I choose name professional than db table name can be professionals while if I name it person then table name will be "people" (plural of person)? How exactly I should name my models and what should I do if I name it like "Person" and plural of it is totally different word? How excatly should I name models and dbtables while professional and person both seems to be fine for model name. I know django or any framework will accept any model name but what is better approach? I will be using "Professional" through out the site but there will also be students who will be making a personal/professional account so person seems to be more generic term in real meanings. So please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/338156/434171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that table names should not be in plural. That said and since your db will contain students too, Person I think is the best option. Imho table/schema definition is more important than table names. In the end the table name doesn't matter that much.

Comment: In table schema, it has most of things of professional other than one field named "is_student", may be later on I will add more fields about students but not right now