# yii2 : can't get data from two table with active record

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I want get data from two table `comments`,`users`.
`comments` have `hasOne` relation with `users`

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

i want get `comments.comment_id`,`comments.comment_content`,`comments.user_id` from `comments` table and `uses.user_name` , `users.user_display_name` from `users` table to use in `gridview` widget.

i use

```
$res = Comments::find()
            ->select([
                'comments.comment_id',
                'comments.comment_content',
                'comments.user_id',
                'users.user_id',
                'users.user_display_name',
                'users.user_name',
            ])
            ->innerJoinWith('user')
            ->all();
```

this code get `comments` field but i can't get `users.user_name`,`users.user_display_name` from database.

How should I do it?

note:  user table in database is `users` but when i create model with Gii,relation method declare as `getUser()`, i don't know why.

**update 1:**

`comments` table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comments`;
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_content` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_approved` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  KEY `fk_comment_sms_id` (`sms_id`),
  KEY `fk_commetn_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_sms_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sms_id`) REFERENCES `sms` (`sms_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_commetn_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_phone_number` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `user_status` enum('active','deactive','delete') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'deactive',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_user_sign` (`user_name`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `u_user_email` (`user_email`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How are you using `$res` to display data?

Comment: $res is model object(i think) and i use `foreach($res as $comment)`, then get value with field name like : `$comment->comment_content`. widget use it automatically.

Comment: Do you get anything with `$comment->user->user_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you're displaying or testing if the query returned any data but you should read up on relations in Yii.

[Working with Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data)
[Lazy and Eager Loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-and-eager-loading)

With lazy loading the data doesn't exist until you try to access it so may not appear in things like `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: i use xdebug and `var_dump` to see result and `var_dump` has limit diplay result(i fix it).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend renaming your tables to `comment` and `user`. Read here: [Table Naming Dilemma: Singular vs. Plural Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names) why you should use singular names.

The reason Gii generates `getUser` and not `getUsers` is because of the `hasOne` relationship. It's getting one -user- and not multiple -user**s**-

Are you sure the relationship definition is correct? Is `user_id` the PK in the users table and the FK in the comments table? And are you sure there is correct data in the DB?

Comment: update tables query, i use navicat to enter data in db and i'm sure there is correct data in DB

Comment: And if you do a `print_r($comment)` in your foreach, do you see the user_name and user_user_display_name?

Comment: i use @Alex help in above, and it's work. use `$comment->user->user_name`.