# How to maintain mysql database connections and queries in a java based Restful server

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm developing a java based Restful Api server. And I'm using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/).

The server is gonna be providing [Yelp](http://yelp.com), [Foursquare](http://Foursquare.com) like backend.

I'm starting with using only one Mysql database to store all my tables, such as `users`, `reviews`, `businesses`.

My question is, in my Restful server, how to I maintain the connection, or maybe queries to the database in order to get better performance. For example,

- Do I have to create different connections for a bunch of similar queries?
- Do I have to put each query into different threads?
- If so, how should I structure my code to implement all these. Can I put all database related tasks in a Singleton class?
- Are there popular frameworks or libraries to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Use a Connection Pool.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is that a Java class? or a library?

Comment: There are many Java connection pools. [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [BoneCP](http://www.jolbox.com/), [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), etc.

Comment: May I recommend you reconsider using plural names for database tables (`user`, not `users`, etc.). It sounds petty but it'll really help you understand the entities which you are modeling if you use singular names. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5841297/963076

Comment: @ryvantage Thanks mate!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Great, which one would you suggest?

Comment: Primarily *opinion* based. I'd suggest using the one you like best. You may want to check-out the [benchmarks](http://jolbox.com/). BoneCP is very nice. Or use Spring and the [Spring Guides](https://spring.io/guides), for example [Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) and [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, I've looked into BoneCP. So I should just keep a single instance of the `BoneCP` instance across the entire project, and simply use `boneCP.getConnection()` to get a connection whenever we wanna use one? Are there other tricks that I've to keep in mind? And how about `stmt.executeQuery()`, do I have to put this one into a separate thread every time I make a query?

Comment: @ScottZhu Generally. And, what do you intend to do in the first thread while the client is waiting? I think you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok, let's say I gonna have many endpoints like `/login`, `/signup`, `/businesses`, `/reviews`, and many front-end clients might be calling it at the same time. In each endpoint is where I might need to call BoneCP to do different queries on my backend database, so that I have the right data to response to my front-end clients. Does that make sense?

Comment: Of course you could have multiple endpoints. What are you asking?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My question is, in the place where I handle all the endpoints, should I just keep a single instance of the BoneCP instance across the entire project, and simply use `boneCP.getConnection()` to get a connection whenever we wanna use one? Are there other tricks that I've to keep in mind? And how about `stmt.executeQuery()`, do I have to put this one into a separate thread every time I make a query?

Comment: @ScottZhu Just use one pool, and call `getConnection()` when you need to use it. I wouldn't use multiple threads.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Great, thanks mate!