# What is the use of uc after constraint?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT **uc**_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
)
```

Comment: That's just a part of the constraint name `uc_PersonID`.

Comment: Yes, that's just prefix in the name. May be that's in your company's naming convention. Other may be suffix like: PersonID_cons1, Person_ID, Person_index1, ....

Comment: I suppose uc means unique constraint. An internal enterprise notation to categorize the type of constraints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely good practice to name your constraints (otherwise SQL Server will name them with a random name, which makes it really difficult to upgrade more than one system with a general upgrade script).

It is good practice to use a prefix to see what type of constraint this is.

Common are

- UQ, UC or UK for unique constraint / unique key
- FK for foreign key
- PK for the primary key
- CK for a CHECK constraint

#### UPDATE

And it is good practice to add the table's name to the constraint (to avoid ambiguities). In your case this was:

```
CONSTRAINT uc_Persons_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

Btw (*Naming convention*): It is quite common to use table names in singular form (Person instead of Persons). Read here: [Table Naming Dilemma: Singular vs. Plural Names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338156/5089204)

Comment: I'd say the opposite, table names should be pluralis, because you store several persons in a table. Column name however, singularis.

Comment: @jarlh :-) We might start a discussion, yeah! But jokes aside: It is opinion based (therefore the linked question is closed as opinion based). I think we can agree on one statement: Keep it consistent! The points collected in the highest voted answer there are rather convincing actually :-)