# Best way to design table with many category columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Book table with columns like

Book-id title   description    author         category1 category2 category3

100001  Micro  blah blah Michael Crichton  SciFi    Action   Mystery

But the categories available is about 22 each book is allowed 3
Any category column can have any of the categories

For searching this set up, it becomes extremely hard and there are about 6000 books so far listed on it.

What would be the best way to do categories in a database design to make searching easier?
I tried giving them all a index column but that caused the table to throw a 1070 error.
Thanks in Advance Gary

Comment: This is why MySQL is called a "relational database", you have to create relations. In your case, create a `book_category` table, and link your books to the categories (an enum, or another table).

Comment: As you can see from my question, I am not that familiar with database design and have managed by good luck to have a system that just about works. But it is shockingly bad and I look forward to all suggestions for correcting my lack of basic knowledge. I have been pondering over different ways to do it for days, in the hope I would not have to ask for help.

Comment: You should stop the guess work and learn how to use the technology first. Do tutorials, read the database documentation, buy books...

Comment: Yep I just did but managed to confuse myself into what would be the best approach, the answer you gave and Mayank elaborated on did seem to me the most likely best approach.
I just thought I would confirm that by asking such a simple question, if this was the wrong thing for me to do then I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this architecture:

- book_detail: To hold book related information with an auto-increment id
- category: to hold categories list in it with an auto-increment id
- book_category: to hold the mapping of book -> categories, it a one to many mapping, means one book can map to different categories by its primary key like:

`book_detail.id -> category.id`

Comment: I edited your answer, the good practices suggest to use singular tablenames. See this answer for more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names

Comment: @GuillaumeF. thanks mate