# What is the definition of table name in sql standard

Tags: iso, ansi-sql, sql

I browsed [ISO/IEC 9075:1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), I have not found any information about the definition of table name, such as what kind of characters should be used, the limitation of the length. And I also browsed ISO/IEC 9075:2011, the lexical definition about token is really difficult to me, I can not understand it. Could anyone explain it for me? This question can be simplified to this one, can special characters such as period be used in table name according to the standard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names

Comment: That link doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Regular identifiers use A-Z, and digits [0-9] (except in first position) - not reserved words. Delimited identifiers may include all characters, e.g. `"Very 4 odd %&() name?"` and also reserved words, like `"TABLE"` (bad idea!)

Comment: Exactly as @jarlh wrote, there's just one additional character in regular identifiers, the underscore `_`

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks for the correction! (I blame this morning's lack of coffee!) Also, I forgot to mention max length 128 characters,.