# What does symfony recommend for database table names?

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I have a debate with a co-worker whether we should use singular or plural for database table names (the Doctrine annotations). He suggests singular names, but i find it way more logical to have it in plural names and i was wondering if there is any recommendation from Symfony because i couldn’t find any.

Thoughts?

Comment: Symfony tries to abstract the implementation details as much as possible and knows nothing about tables and even a databases. That's why you won't find such a recommendation in it's documentation. It's up to you and your co-worker to agree on a convention :)

Comment: As doctrine is an ORM and its about objects it should be singular. `$car = new Car()` so you have created one new car instance and not multiple.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by Alexander Marinov, this is not a Symfony question, Symfony does not have any recommendation for this - this is more of a database design question - and is a duplicate of many questions here on stackoverflow and around the internet as such.

But to give you some ideas, you have several options:

**Use singular:**
This is most commonly used. If you are concerned that the table name in singular makes no sense think about it this way - the table name represents one record in it, not all of them.

This also makes your code sensible - as already stated by Fabian, you want to create singulars in code.

**Use plural:**
It might make sense in database, but the entity name and code will be ugly - just think of `$car = new Cars();`

**Use both singular and plural:**
Doctrine allows you to specify different table name than entity name using the [@Table](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#table) annotation, but this is not very common practice, again, if you think of the table name as a representation of one record in the table, and not collective name for all records in it, this option does not make much sense.

There is a lot of discussion about this around the internet, look around, get some ideas and then its up to you and your colleague what you agree on.
Some examples:
[Table Naming Dilemma: Singular vs. Plural Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names)
https://medium.com/@fbnlsr/the-table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-dc260d90aaff

Comment: Why would a table name represent only one record if in the real world you would label everything in plural. You would label your apple bag "apples", your sock drawer "socks", your cable drawer "cables". You would never name it with a single item it includes.

`$car = new Cars();` is a bad example. `Car` in this context is a class. It cannot store any data, it just describes how data must be stored. A database table does store data. You cannot store a class in a database, but an array and you would never name an array singular. E.g. `for (car of car) {}` does not work.

Comment: Mathematically speaking a table (or relation) consists of data structured in rows and columns. A database table optionally defines how this data must be structured. It is NOT a must though. You can just define 100 BLOB columns and store whatever you like.

Queries are also never targeting single rows. Even `where users.id = 3` does not mean "give me the id of a single user" it does mean "filter all rows by the ones that have the value `3` in column `id` of table `users`. SQL always returns a set even if that set happens to be a single record.