# Rest api design for get a field of nested object

Tags: rest, api

suppose we have class below

```
class Blog {
    Integer id;
    List<Post> posts;
}

class Post {
     Integer id;
     List<String> tags;
}
```

If I want to make an endpoint for all tags of a certain blog, what is proper option. And return type is List.

`blogs/{blog-id}/posts?field=tags`

`blogs/{blog-id}/post-tags`

`blogs/{blog-id}/posts/tags`

`blogs/{blog-id}/post/tags`

Or any suggestion is fine. Which one is most approporiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the ones you listed, I would opt for either the first or second, depending on use case.

`blogs/{blog-id}/posts?field=tags`: This indicates that you are wanting just the `tags` field for the items in the collection. I would expect there to still be an object per post in the response, but only the `tags` field to be present. If you wanted a distinct list, you would need to process those in the client.

`blogs/{blog-id}/post-tags`: This would be used to return a single, distinct list of tags applied.

Here is why I wouldn't go with the others:

`blogs/{blog-id}/posts/tags`: This would probably be viewed as a post titled `tags` instead of returning all the tags on posts.

`blogs/{blog-id}/post/tags`: In addition to the above, this implies a single post, not a collection.

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is most approporiate?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are compliant with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  The machines don't care -- as far as they are concerned, the URI are just cache keys, nothing more than that.

See also: Stefan Tilkov [REST: I Don't Think It Means What You Think It Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

Spelling conventions for URI are useful for humans; they are much like variable naming conventions, where we value familiarity and consistency *in a given context*, without absolutes on right and wrong.

```
blogs/{blog-id}/posts/tags
blogs/{blog-id}/post/tags
```

It might be useful to review the singular vs plural arguments for [database table naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names).

```
blogs/{blog-id}/posts?field=tags
blogs/{blog-id}/post-tags
blogs/{blog-id}/posts/tags
```

A reason that you might prefer the latter form is [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), in particular the fact that you can use [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) to express one identifier in terms of another.

```
blogs/{blog-id}/posts/tags + ../images -> blogs/{blog-id}/posts/images
```

There's no particular reason that the `tags` segment needs to be under `posts`, or even under `blogs` -- this spelling is also "fine", assuming that you don't run into problems with ambiguity:

```
/tags/{blog-id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it consistent with the URI you have for posts. Lets assume you have the following;

`/posts`  Returns links to all posts
`/posts/tags`  Reads tags for all posts
`/posts/id`  Reads a post
`/posts/id/tags`  Reads the tags for a post

`/blogs` Returns links to all blogs
`/blogs/id` Reads a blog

Now if you want to read tags for all posts belonging to a blog it makes sense to chain the URIs together;

`/blogs/id/posts/tags` Reads tags for all posts belonging to blog.