# Filtering related_name field, in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter `related_name` field with a query if it's possible. I serialize the tables.

```
class ProjectsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ["id", "project_id", "project_name", "tasks"]
        depth = 1
```

Above in the fields list. `tasks` is the `related_table` so in the tasks table I have `task_created_at` field and when I retrieve the projects table. I want to filter it by that field.

```
def get_projects(request):
  projects = Projects.objects.filter(task_created_at__startswith="2020-04")
  serializer = ProjectsSerializers(projects, many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

Of course this: `task_created_at__startswith="2020-04"` isn't working. Because `task_created_at` is not in the projects. it's in the `related_name` which is `tasks`. So is there a way to filter tasks with getting projects

and the relevent models:

```
class Projects(models.Model):

    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "projects"

class Tasks(models.Model):

    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks', blank=True, null=True)
    task_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    task_total_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    task_created_at = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad_kind

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tasks"
```

the example data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "order_id": null,
        "project_id": "23123",
        "project_name": "プレサンス グラン 茨木駅前",
        "company_name": null,
        "analytics_id": null,
        "advertisements": [],
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "task_total_price": null,
                "task_created_at": "2020-04-02",
                "task_due_date": "2020-04-07",
                "task_modified_at": "2020-04-07T06:42:41.447Z",
                "projects": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "task_total_price": null,
                "task_created_at": "2020-02-02",
                "task_due_date": "2020-03-07",
                "task_modified_at": "2020-04-07T06:42:41.447Z",
                "projects": 6
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant models please.

Comment: I added in the question @ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can JOIN two tables/models by **`__`** (a double underscore).

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def get_projects(request):
    projects = Projects.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('tasks', queryset=Tasks.objects.filter(task_created_at__istartswith='2020-04'))
    ).filter(tasks__task_created_at__istartswith='2020-04')

    serializer = ProjectsSerializers(projects, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data))
```

**Reference**

- [**Lookups that span relationships**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
- [**`Prefetch(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

Comment: thank you but it says: `TypeError: prefetch_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tasks'`

Comment: @Tay Updated the answer

Comment: yes it's worked out. thank you... could you a bit explain the situation here?

Comment: the filter in the **`Projects`** class will not be applied to the ***related task queryset***

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a *subquery*:

```
def get_projects(request):

    project_ids = Task.objects.filter(
      task_created_at__startswith='2020-04').values('project_id')
    projects = Project.objects.filter(id__in=project_ids)

    serializer = ProjectsSerializers(projects, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also, please don't use [plural table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names) ;-)

Lastly, I'd recommend using a [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) for storing dates, instead of using a `CharField`.

Comment: this way is apart from the `rest_framework`. because now i can't serialize the data and get a json response... and yes, you are right about the `DateTime`

Comment: @Tay I added an update showing how this will work with the DRF serializer

Comment: Thank you and yes, I tried this, but it's retrieving all tasks, not filtering it by task_created_at

Comment: @Tay can you provide example data?

Comment: I added the example data into the question. And as you see there two different `task_created_at` date 2020-04 and 2020-02 and when I try your answer. it returns still both...

Answer (score 0):

To be able to dynamically change the representation of an object, you can modify the serializer. One way to filter the tasks is to provide a `serializers.SerializerMethodField` that filters the tasks dynamically.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = Task
        fields = [ ... your fields ... ]


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filtered_tasks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model  = Project
        fields = ["id", "project_id", "project_name", "filtered_tasks"]
        depth  = 1

    def get_filtered_tasks(self, obj):
        tasks = Task.objects.filter(created_at__startswith="2020-04")
        return TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True).data
```

However, I don't like this approach. I think you should reconsider how you present the data. It feels like your binding the data too hard together. Although, I don't know your use-case so I cannot come with any concrete suggestions.

Also, I've changed the names here so the models are **singular**, as it's the convention.

Comment: acutally, `task_created_at` is a field inside the `tasks` table. Then you mean `tasks__task_created_at__startswith="2020-04"` something like this? `tasks__` before the field is enters the `tasks` table?

Comment: hm, actually I tried that before, but it doesn't filter `tasks`... it just getting all tasks

Comment: but I am trying to filter `tasks` only matches the date while getting all projects...

Comment: yep, I always want to return the projects. `tasks` in projects trying to filter those by the date.

Comment: I understand the way you are doing, but the date I am filtering not constant, I will post it from frontend and so need to filtering in the view. And I found the solution in another answer. But thank you!