# Difference Between Select and SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq

I've been searching the difference between `Select` and `SelectMany` but I haven't been able to find a suitable answer. I need to learn the difference when using LINQ To SQL but all I've found are standard array examples.

Can someone provide a LINQ To SQL example?

Comment: you can look at the code for SelectMany with one function, or with two functions http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc79a642e00b8681

Comment: If you familiar with Kotlin it has quite similar implementations for collections as map aka C# Select and flatMap aka C# SelectMany. Basically Kotlin std library extension functions for collections has similarity to C# Linq library.

Comment: Would one agree that `SelectFromMany` would be a much more descriptive name than `SelectMany`?

Answer (score 1955, accepted):

`SelectMany` flattens queries that return lists of lists. For example

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Person> people = new List<Person>();

// Select gets a list of lists of phone numbers
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PhoneNumber>> phoneLists = people.Select(p => p.PhoneNumbers);

// SelectMany flattens it to just a list of phone numbers.
IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = people.SelectMany(p => p.PhoneNumbers);

// And to include data from the parent in the result: 
// pass an expression to the second parameter (resultSelector) in the overload:
var directory = people
   .SelectMany(p => p.PhoneNumbers,
               (parent, child) => new { parent.Name, child.Number });
```

[Live Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNyymI)

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428940/how-to-flatten-nested-objects-with-linq-expression) on nesting SelectMany to flatten out a nested hierarchical structure.

Comment: To understand resultSelector more The below link helps http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/

Comment: One more demo with results from parent: https://dotnetfiddle.net/flcdCC

Answer (score 253):

Select many is like [cross join operation in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) where it takes the cross product.
For example if we have

```
Set A={a,b,c}
Set B={x,y}
```

Select many can be used to get the following set

```
{ (x,a) , (x,b) , (x,c) , (y,a) , (y,b) , (y,c) }
```

Note that here we take the all the possible combinations that can be made from the elements of set A and set B.

Here is a LINQ example you can try

```
List<string> animals = new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> number = new List<int>() { 10, 20 };

var mix = number.SelectMany(num => animals, (n, a) => new { n, a });
```

the mix will have following elements in flat structure like

```
{(10,cat), (10,dog), (10,donkey), (20,cat), (20,dog), (20,donkey)}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to thank you for this, it saved me a lot! :) It can be useful to have a reference to those codes too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479980/select-all-unique-combinations-of-a-single-list-with-no-repeats-using-linq
Cheers!

Comment: SelectMany doesn't have to be used like that. It has an option to just take one function too.

Comment: I dunno if it's right to say that this is how `SelectMany` *is*. Rather, this is a way that `SelectMany` can be used, but is not actually the normal way of using it.

Comment: This was the simplest answer for me to understand.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah it may well be the answer that you understood most easily, but if this were the only answer you read then I wouldn't expect that you actually understood what SelectMany() is doing; this doesn't at all represent what the function does in the general case - it just provides a particular (unusual) thing that it is *capable* of achieving.

Answer (score 155):

[image]

```
var players = db.SoccerTeams.Where(c => c.Country == "Spain")
                            .SelectMany(c => c.players);

foreach(var player in players)
{
    Console.WriteLine(player.LastName);
}
```

1. De Gea
2. Alba
3. Costa
4. Villa
5. Busquets

...

Comment: could you add an example for select to complete this answer :)

Comment: @Harry: from a previous sample, but developed a bit: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ku6kLR

Answer (score 83):

`SelectMany()` lets you collapse a multidimensional sequence in a way that would otherwise require a second `Select()` or loop.

More details at this [blog post](http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/differnce-between-select-and-selectmany-in-linq/).

Comment: But the first one return Enumerables type of Children the second example return type of Parents ? Actually I am little bit confused,would you open it up little bit more ?

Comment: Other way around, actually.  The second will completely flatten the hierarchy of enumerables, so that you get Children back.  Try the article at the link I added, see if that helps.

Comment: The first one does not appear to be legal.  I think the poster got confused himself.  The second one would return an enumerable of parents.

Comment: Thanks, well actually yeah the examples were kinda confusing tho :) but thanks again for trying to help me.

Answer (score 40):

There are several overloads to `SelectMany`. One of them allows you to keep trace of any relationship between parent and children while traversing the hierarchy.

*Example*: suppose you have the following structure: `League -> Teams -> Player`.

You can easily return a flat collection of players. However you may lose any reference to the team the player is part of.

Fortunately there is an overload for such purpose:

```
var teamsAndTheirLeagues = 
         from helper in leagues.SelectMany
               ( l => l.Teams
                 , ( league, team ) => new { league, team } )
                      where helper.team.Players.Count > 2 
                           && helper.league.Teams.Count < 10
                           select new 
                                  { LeagueID = helper.league.ID
                                    , Team = helper.team 
                                   };
```

The previous example is taken from [Dan's IK blog](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/). I strongly recommend you take a look at it.

Answer (score 26):

I understand `SelectMany` to work like a join shortcut.

So you can:

```
var orders = customers
             .Where(c => c.CustomerName == "Acme")
             .SelectMany(c => c.Orders);
```

Comment: The provided example works, but **SelectMany** does not exactly work like a join. A join allows to "use" any field of the original table plus any field of the joined table. But here you have to specify an object of a list attached to the original table. For example, `.SelectMany(c => new {c.CompanyName, c.Orders.ShippedDate});` would not work. SelectMany is rather flattening the list of lists - and you can pick any (but only one at a time) of the contained lists for the result. For comparison: [Inner join in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332/1016343).

Answer (score 26):

The **SelectMany()** method is used to **flatten** a sequence in which each of the elements of the sequence is a separate.

I have class `user` same like this

```
class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

**main:**

```
var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User { UserName = "Reza" , Roles = new List<string>{"Superadmin" } },
                new User { UserName = "Amin" , Roles = new List<string>{"Guest","Reseption" } },
                new User { UserName = "Nima" , Roles = new List<string>{"Nurse","Guest" } },
            };

var query = users.SelectMany(user => user.Roles, (user, role) => new { user.UserName, role });

foreach (var obj in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
//output

//{ UserName = Reza, role = Superadmin }
//{ UserName = Amin, role = Guest }
//{ UserName = Amin, role = Reseption }
//{ UserName = Nima, role = Nurse }
//{ UserName = Nima, role = Guest }
```

You can use operations on any item of sequence

```
int[][] numbers = {
                new[] {1, 2, 3},
                new[] {4},
                new[] {5, 6 , 6 , 2 , 7, 8},
                new[] {12, 14}
            };

IEnumerable<int> result = numbers
                .SelectMany(array => array.Distinct())
                .OrderBy(x => x);

//output

//{ 1, 2 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 14 }
```

```
 List<List<int>> numbers = new List<List<int>> {
                new List<int> {1, 2, 3},
                new List<int> {12},
                new List<int> {5, 6, 5, 7},
                new List<int> {10, 10, 10, 12}
            };

 IEnumerable<int> result = numbers
                .SelectMany(list => list)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x=>x);

//output

// { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12 }
```

Comment: What if one or more of the lists happen to be null, can you still aggregate the others? I'm getting an error because of having a couple of null results.

Answer (score 13):

Select is a simple one-to-one projection from source element to a result element. Select-
Many is used when there are multiple from clauses in a query expression: each element in the original sequence is used to generate a new sequence.

Answer (score 9):

Some SelectMany may not be necessary. Below 2 queries give the same result.

```
Customers.Where(c=>c.Name=="Tom").SelectMany(c=>c.Orders)

Orders.Where(o=>o.Customer.Name=="Tom")
```

For 1-to-Many relationship,

1. if Start from "1", SelectMany is needed, it flattens the many.
2. if Start from "Many", SelectMany is not needed. (**still be able to filter from "1"**, also this is simpler than below standard join query)

---

```
from o in Orders
join c in Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.ID
where c.Name == "Tom"
select o
```

Answer (score 9):

The formal description for SelectMany() is:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
> the resulting sequences into one sequence.

SelectMany() flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence, and invokes a result selector function on each element therein.

```
class PetOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<String> Pets { get; set; }
}

public static void SelectManyEx()
{
     PetOwner[] petOwners =
         { new PetOwner { Name="Higa, Sidney",
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
           new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi, Ronen",
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
           new PetOwner { Name="Price, Vernette",
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } } };

// Query using SelectMany().
IEnumerable<string> query1 = petOwners.SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);

Console.WriteLine("Using SelectMany():");

// Only one foreach loop is required to iterate
// through the results since it is a
// one-dimensional collection.
foreach (string pet in query1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pet);
}

// This code shows how to use Select()
// instead of SelectMany().
IEnumerable<List<String>> query2 =
    petOwners.Select(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);

Console.WriteLine("\nUsing Select():");

// Notice that two foreach loops are required to
// iterate through the results
// because the query returns a collection of arrays.
foreach (List<String> petList in query2)
{
    foreach (string pet in petList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pet);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
}

/*
   This code produces the following output:

    Using SelectMany():
    Scruffy
    Sam
    Walker
    Sugar
    Scratches
    Diesel

   Using Select():
   Scruffy
   Sam

   Walker
   Sugar

   Scratches
   Diesel
  */
```

The main difference is the result of each method while SelectMany() returns a flattern results; the Select() returns a list of list instead of a flattern result set.

Therefor the result of SelectMany is a list  like

> {Scruffy,  Sam , Walker,  Sugar,  Scratches , Diesel}

which you can iterate each item by just one foreach. But with the result of select you need  an extra foreach loop to iterate through the results  because the query returns a collection of arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Just for an alternate view that may help some functional programmers out there:

- `Select` is `map`
- `SelectMany` is `bind` (or `flatMap` for your Scala/Kotlin people)

Answer (score 4):

Without getting too technical - database with many Organizations, each with many Users:-

```
var orgId = "123456789";

var userList1 = db.Organizations
                   .Where(a => a.OrganizationId == orgId)
                   .SelectMany(a => a.Users)
                   .ToList();

var userList2 = db.Users
                   .Where(a => a.OrganizationId == orgId)
                   .ToList();
```

both return *the same* ApplicationUser list for the selected Organization.

The first "projects" from Organization to Users, the second queries the Users table directly.

Answer (score 4):

It's more clear when the query return a string (an array of char):

For example if the list 'Fruits' contains 'apple'

**'Select' returns the string:**

```
Fruits.Select(s=>s) 

[0]: "apple"
```

**'SelectMany' flattens the string:**

```
Fruits.SelectMany(s=>s)

[0]: 97  'a'
[1]: 112 'p'
[2]: 112 'p'
[3]: 108 'l'
[4]: 101 'e'
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider this example :

```
        var array = new string[2]
        {
            "I like what I like",
            "I like what you like"
        };
        //query1 returns two elements sth like this:
        //fisrt element would be array[5]  :[0] = "I" "like" "what" "I" "like"
        //second element would be array[5] :[1] = "I" "like" "what" "you" "like"
        IEnumerable<string[]> query1 = array.Select(s => s.Split(' ')).Distinct();

        //query2 return back flat result sth like this :
        // "I" "like" "what" "you"
        IEnumerable<string> query2 = array.SelectMany(s => s.Split(' ')).Distinct();
```

So as you see duplicate values like "I" or "like" have been removed from query2 because "SelectMany" flattens and projects across multiple sequences.
But query1 returns sequence of string arrays. and since there are two different arrays in query1 (first and second element), nothing would be removed.

Comment: probably better to now include .Distinct() at end and state it outputs "I" "like" "what" "I" "like" "I" "like" "what" "you" "like"

Answer (score 3):

The `SelectMany` method knocks down an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into an `IEnumerable<T>`, like communism, every element is behaved in the same manner(a stupid guy has same rights of a genious one).

```
var words = new [] { "a,b,c", "d,e", "f" };
var splitAndCombine = words.SelectMany(x => x.Split(','));
// returns { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an array of countries

```
var countries = new[] { "France", "Italy" };
```

If you perform `Select` on `countries`, you will get each element of the array as `IEnumerable<T>`

```
IEnumerable<string> selectQuery = countries.Select(country => country);
```

In the above code, the `country` represents a string that refers to each country in the array. now iterate over `selectQuery` to get countries:

```
foreach(var country in selectQuery)
    Console.WriteLine(country);

// output
//
// France
// Italy
```

If you want to print every character of countries you have to use nested `foreach`

```
foreach (var country in selectQuery)
{
    foreach (var charOfCountry in country)
    {
        Console.Write(charOfCountry + ", ");
    }
}

// output

// F, r, a, n, c, e, I, t, a, l, y,
```

OK. now try to perform `SelectMany` on countries. This time `SelectMany` gets each country as `string` (as before) and because of `string` type is a collection of chars, `SelectMany` tries to divide each country into its constituent parts (chars) and then returns a collection of chars as `IEnumerable<T>`

```
IEnumerable<char> selectManyQuery = countries.SelectMany(country => country);
```

In the above code, the country represents a string that refers to each country in the array as before, but the return value is the chars of each country

Actually `SelectMany` likes to fetch two levels inside of collections and flatten the second level as `IEnumerable<T>`

Now iterate over `selectManyQuery` to get chars of each country:

```
foreach(var charOfCountry in selectManyQuery)
    Console.Write(charOfCountry + ", ");

// output

// F, r, a, n, c, e, I, t, a, l, y,
```

Answer (score 2):

One more example how SelectMany + Select can be used in order to accumulate sub array objects data.

Suppose we have users with they phones:

```
class Phone { 
    public string BasePart = "555-xxx-xxx"; 
}

class User { 
    public string Name = "Xxxxx";
    public List<Phone> Phones; 
}
```

Now we need to select all phones' BaseParts of all users:

```
var usersArray = new List<User>(); // array of arrays
List<string> allBaseParts = usersArray.SelectMany(ua => ua.Phones).Select(p => p.BasePart).ToList();
```

Comment: Which do you think is better? Yours or `usersArray.SelectMany(ua => ua.Phones.Select(p => p.BasePart))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example with an initialized small collection for testing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                OrderID = "orderID1",
                OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>
                {
                    new OrderLine
                    {
                        ProductSKU = "SKU1",
                        Quantity = 1
                    },
                    new OrderLine
                    {
                        ProductSKU = "SKU2",
                        Quantity = 2
                    },
                    new OrderLine
                    {
                        ProductSKU = "SKU3",
                        Quantity = 3
                    }
                }
            },
            new Order
            {
                OrderID = "orderID2",
                OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>
                {
                    new OrderLine
                    {
                        ProductSKU = "SKU4",
                        Quantity = 4
                    },
                    new OrderLine
                    {
                        ProductSKU = "SKU5",
                        Quantity = 5
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        //required result is the list of all SKUs in orders
        List<string> allSKUs = new List<string>();

        //With Select case 2 foreach loops are required
        var flattenedOrdersLinesSelectCase = orders.Select(o => o.OrderLines);
        foreach (var flattenedOrderLine in flattenedOrdersLinesSelectCase)
        {
            foreach (OrderLine orderLine in flattenedOrderLine)
            {
                allSKUs.Add(orderLine.ProductSKU);
            }
        }

        //With SelectMany case only one foreach loop is required
        allSKUs = new List<string>();
        var flattenedOrdersLinesSelectManyCase = orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderLines);
        foreach (var flattenedOrderLine in flattenedOrdersLinesSelectManyCase)
        {
            allSKUs.Add(flattenedOrderLine.ProductSKU);
        }

       //If the required result is flattened list which has OrderID, ProductSKU and Quantity,
       //SelectMany with selector is very helpful to get the required result
       //and allows avoiding own For loops what according to my experience do code faster when
       // hundreds of thousands of data rows must be operated
        List<OrderLineForReport> ordersLinesForReport = (List<OrderLineForReport>)orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderLines,
            (o, ol) => new OrderLineForReport
            {
                OrderID = o.OrderID,
                ProductSKU = ol.ProductSKU,
                Quantity = ol.Quantity
            }).ToList();
    }
}
class Order
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
class OrderLine
{
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
class OrderLineForReport
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A select operator is used to select value from a collection and SelectMany operator is used to selecting values from a collection of collection i.e. nested collection.

Comment: IMO this question doesn't need new answers. Moreover, your answer isn't really clear.

Answer (score -1):

Example with `SelectMany`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyObject
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public int Value4 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Assuming you have a list of MyObject
        List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>
        {
            // Add your objects here
            new MyObject { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3, Value4 = 4 },
            // ... other objects
        };

        // Use LINQ to concatenate all integer properties into a single list
        List<int> concatenatedList = objects
            .SelectMany(obj => new List<int> { obj.Value1, obj.Value2, obj.Value3, obj.Value4 })
            .ToList();

        // concatenatedList now contains all integer values from all objects
    }
}
```

If you use Entity Framework with `SelectMany` you might encounter an exception like this though:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'x => new List`1() {Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])(x.Value1), Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])(x.Value2), Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])(x.Value3), Void Add(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])(x.Value4)}
' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

In that case you would have to do it like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
// ... other using statements ...

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Assuming your DbContext is dbContext and you have a DbSet<MyObject> Objects
        var objectsQuery = dbContext.Objects.AsEnumerable(); // Switching to in-memory processing

        // Now perform the SelectMany operation
        List<int> concatenatedList = objectsQuery
            .SelectMany(obj => new List<int> { obj.Value1, obj.Value2, obj.Value3, obj.Value4 })
            .ToList();

        // concatenatedList now contains all integer values from all objects
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` etc will load the entire dataset into memory, which might not be efficient for very large datasets.

Comment: If you vote down please add a comment why. Hard to improve answers otherwise

Answer (score -3):

It is the best way to understand i think.

```
            var query =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 10)
                .SelectMany(ints => Enumerable.Range(1, 10), (a, b) => $"{a} * {b} = {a * b}")
                .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, query));

        Console.Read();
```

Multiplication Table example.

Comment: Only if meaning of "best" has changed dramatically.

Comment: so this is the best way u think ?? then what is the difficult way of thinking ??