# Lambda and Nested Objects

Tags: linq, lambda

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627170/how-to-query-a-nested-list-using-a-lambda-expression) answer and it goes in part to solving my issue.

However, what I need is the following.

Given I have an object;

```
Product
  string code
  List<suitability> items
```

and then i have this object;

```
Suitability
  key
  value
```

Each Product has a variable amount of [items] and the key/value pairs differ from product to product.

When searching I am given a list of Suitability objects.  I now need to search all the products that contain (all) of the supplied suitability objects.

So for example a product may have dental = true and therapies = true.

I may get a request for all products that have dental = true and therapies = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) (from the authors of LinqPad) you can build up a query from a set of conditions not known at compile time. The following should be sufficient:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();

foreach (Suitability criteria in searchCriteria)
{
    string tempKey = criteria.Key;
    string tempValue = criteria.Value;
    predicate = predicate.And(p => 
                     p.Items.Any(s => s.Key == tempKey && s.Value == tempValue));
}

return dataContext.Products.Where(predicate.Compile());
```

UPDATE: Heres some sample code that I have tested which works using an IEnumerable as the source, the resulting set `productsResult` contains the first and second products in `products` list:

```
var searchCriteria = new List<Suitability>()
    {
        new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="b" },
        new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="c" }
    };

var products = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product()
            {
                Items = new List<Suitability>() {
                            new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="b" },
                            new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="c" }}
            },
        new Product()
            {
                Items = new List<Suitability>() {
                            new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="b" },
                            new Suitability() { Key="a", Value="c" },
                            new Suitability() { Key="b", Value="c" }}
            },
        new Product()
            {
                Items = new List<Suitability>() {
                            new Suitability() { Key="c", Value="d" }}
            }
    };

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();

    foreach (Suitability criteria in searchCriteria)
    {
        string tempKey = criteria.Key;
        string tempValue = criteria.Value;
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Items.Any(
                         s => s.Key == tempKey && s.Value == tempValue));
    }

    IEnumerable<Product> productsResult = products.Where(predicate.Compile());
```

Comment: @Simon, I tried implementing this but then I remembered I don't have a datacontext as this is not LINQ to SQL and when I apply this to my IEnumerable<Product> list I get an error. Error The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @griegs add .Compile() to get the Func out of the Expression `predicate`...I have updated my answer.

Comment: I've changed my mind and selected this as the prefered answer.  Works a treat thank you.  I still have to agree with @Aaronaught that the approach of using the EAV model is not ideal but when you have no alternative...

Comment: @griegs Thanks!! No argument from me on the EAV model not being optimal but as you are locked in and have no choice I definitely prefer the simplicity gained using the PredicateBuilder

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'd like to point out that key-value pairs (AKA EAV model) are a poor choice for representing this kind of data, and this question is a perfect example of why - it's much, much harder to search for arbitrary collections of attributes than it is to search for specific properties.

Of course, it can still be done:

```
var suitableProducts =
    from p in products
    where
        p.Items.Any(s => s.Key == "dental" && s.Value == "true") &&
        p.Items.Any(s => s.Key == "therapies" && s.Value == "false")
    select p;
```

It's just not as easy to write or efficient as querying on a `Product` class that actually has `dental` and `therapies` properties as opposed to nested attributes.

If you the number of items you need to *query on* can change, then the easiest way to handle that is to chain together filters:

```
var searchItems = ...
var result = products;
foreach (var searchItem in searchItems)
{
    result = result.Where(p =>
        p.Items.Any(s => s.Key == searchItem.Key &&
                         s.Value == searchItem.Value));
}
// Do something with result
```

If you're looking for a more "functional" way to do it without chaining then:

```
var suitabilityConditions = searchItems.Select(i =>
    (Predicate<Product>)(p => p.Items.Any(s => 
        s.Key == searchItem.Key && s.Value == searchItem.Value)));
Predicate<Product> match = p => suitabilityConditions.All(c => c(p));
var suitableProducts = products.Where(match);
```

Comment: @Aaronaught, thanks for this but I can't code each line like you have.  I may be given 2 items or 10.  As for the approach (EAV) what model would you suggest where each product has a variable number of items attached to it?

Comment: @griegs: Added a version for a dynamic number of items.  As for what I would suggest - I would suggest not having a design where each product can have arbitrary sets of attributes.  Such designs are anti-patterns, and may *sometimes* be necessary but are usually the result of a combination of vague requirements and a desire to lower maintenance costs through end-user customization.  Know that it will actually raise TCO due to myriad issues like this (another issue being that attributes are weakly-typed - what happens if you want to sort?); better to fix the vague requirements instead.

Comment: I hear you and this was discussed but the boss pointed out that we need a way to change the number of items associated to a product to accommodate the businesses changes of mind on a monthly basis.

Comment: Good luck.  Unfortunately it's likely that he will learn the hard way how much more it costs to maintain such a design than it does to simply dedicate some development resources to implementing said business changes when they come up.