# Simple LinQ question: convert [][] to []

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

I would like to get collection or list of Item objects, but I get array of arrays now.

```
Item[][] s = employees.Select(e => e.Orders.Select(o => new Item(e.ID, o.ID)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Can anyone select me solution to do it?

P.S. just LinQ solution  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany` to concatenate result sets.

```
var items = employees.SelectMany(e => e.Orders.Select(o => new Item(e.ID, o.ID)));
```

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, this can be written somewhat more succinctly and clearly in LINQ syntax:

```
var s = from e in employees
        from o in e.Orders
        select new Item(e.ID, o.ID);
```

Comment: While I agree with this, instead of changing the syntax used, I would have argued that `Orders` should have a reference back to `Employee` and there is no need for `Item`.

Comment: +1. Note that this syntax is actually translated into SelectMany. Use whatever you find more readable. The generated code is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

The extension method you're looking for is called "SelectMany": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `Enumerables.SelectMany()`, see the example in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany).