# Select all unique combinations of a single list, with no repeats, using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers, and I need to create every possible unique combination of the numbers in the list, without repeats, using a LINQ query. So, for example, if I have `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, the combinations would be `1-2`, `1-3`, and `2-3`.

I currently use two `for` loops, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < slotIds.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < slotIds.Count; j++)
    {
        ExpressionInfo info1 = _expressions[i];
        ExpressionInfo info2 = _expressions[j];

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to convert these two `for` loops to LINQ?

Thanks.

Comment: The combinations are always ordered, right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure - you can do it in a single call to `SelectMany` with an embedded call to `Skip`:

```
var query = slotIds.SelectMany((value, index) => slotIds.Skip(index + 1),
                               (first, second) => new { first, second });
```

Here's an alternative option, which doesn't use *quite* such an esoteric overload of `SelectMany`:

```
var query = from pair in slotIds.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
            from second in slotIds.Skip(pair.index + 1)
            select new { first = pair.value, second };
```

These do basically the same thing, just in slightly different ways.

Here's another option which is much closer to your original:

```
var query = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, slotIds.Count)
            let first = slotIds[index] // Or use ElementAt
            from second in slotIds.Skip(index + 1)
            select new { first, second };
```

Comment: See this for a discussion on the esoteric first solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991486/select-all-unique-combinations-of-a-single-list-with-no-repeats-using-linq-pa

Comment: @David: I don't believe any of the collections in .NET return elements in a different order when iterated over multiple times with no changes between. We don't care what the order is, so long as it's consistent.

Comment: Dangit, then we have the weirdest bug somewhere, thanks i will delete my 2 comments :p

Comment: @David: If you can reproduce it, by all means create a new question and ping this one with a link :)