# Select all unique combinations of a single list, with no repeats, using LINQ (Part 2)

Tags: c#, linq

John Skeets answer to this question, [Select all unique combinations of a single list, with no repeats, using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479980/select-all-unique-combinations-of-a-single-list-with-no-repeats-using-linq), works awesomely.

However, can someone break down component by component the inner workings of how the first answer is working:

```
List<int> slotIds = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
var query = slotIds.SelectMany((value, index) => slotIds.Skip(index + 1),
                              (first, second) => new { first, second });
```

Comment: And why don't you ask that in a comment under that answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's roughly equivalent in *concept* to this, although the actual execution model is different of course (lazy etc):

```
for (int i = 0; i < slotIds.Count; i++)
{
    int first = slotIds[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < slotIds.Count; j++)
    {
        int second = slotIds[j];
        results.Add(new { first, second });
    }
}
```

The `SelectMany` taking a projection from `value` and `index` is a way of using both `first` and `i` to make an inner loop. We need the index so that we can skip `index + 1` values, which is equivalent to the `j` loop starting at `i + 1` in the above code.

Does that help? If not, could you pinpoint which bit is confusing?

EDIT: Aargh - I hadn't realized that the other question you were referring to started out with this code! I think it's still useful though, to give the paragraph below something to hang on...

If you understood the alternative (query expression) version of my answer, then the first version is similar, just using an overload of `SelectMany` which allows you to use both the value and index in the "outer" sequence.

Comment: So you are using this overloaded version of SelectMany, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534732.aspx, so the collectionSelector creates the "inner loop",i.e. {2, index=1} {3, index=2} and the result of that feeds the resultSelector (second lambda function)? I understand your other examples, I think my confusion is with the lambda functions and how the second lambda function builds the list.

Comment: @Seth: The collection selector is the bit which gets the equivalent of `i` and `first` in the code in this answer. Those values (i and first) are then used in `resultSelector`.