# Is there something like `continue` to bypass or skip an iteration of query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Take this example:

```
        int[] queryValues1 = new int[10] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] queryValues2 = new int[100]; // this is 0 to 100

        for (int i = 0; i < queryValues2.Length; i++)
        {
            queryValues2[i] = i;
        }

        var queryResult =
            from qRes1 in queryValues1
            from qRes2 in queryValues2
            where qRes1 * qRes2 == 12
            select new { qRes1, qRes2 };

        foreach (var result in queryResult)
        {
            textBox1.Text += result.qRes1 + " * " + result.qRes2 + " = 12" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Obviously this code will result in:

```
1 * 12 = 12
2 * 6 = 12
3 * 4 = 12
4 * 3 = 12
6 * 2 = 12
```

But what I need is only the first 3 lines. That is **I do not want if 2*6 = 12 the query checks if 6*2 is also 12**. Is there a way to filter this in the LINQ query or I have to do it in the foreach loop afterward?

My question just is a sample to show what I mean. so I want to know the way of doing such thing no matter what is the type of object being linqed to!

Comment: Wouldn't you, in this case, simply only take 1-5 as qRes1 to check these?

Comment: @Tom That would still give 3*4 and 4*3.  Though you could make the cutoff `Math.Sqrt(12)` instead of 5.

Comment: Well I want to know how generally this can be done, the code I gave just is a sample. how to skip when `where` works! Damn I dont know how to exactly point to what I mean :P :D

Comment: @mootinator Oops, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Sean87 Why don't you give a sample of how would you do it if there would exist this `continue` keyword? I think this would give us a better idea of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TakeWhile(condition):Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true, and then skips the remaining elements.

```
foreach (var result in queryResult.TakeWhile(x => x.qRes1 <= Math.Sqrt(12)))
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `break;`, not `continue;`. But will answer for the particular case from the OP.

Comment: @sq33G ,"or skip a itteration" So I think OK. In question rather than "continue" to think of a funny expression.

Answer (score 4):

In general the simple solution would be *more where conditions* since the where clauses are what by definition cause LINQ to skip iterations:

```
var queryResult =
    from qRes1 in queryValues1
    from qRes2 in queryValues1
    where qRes1 * qRes2 == 12
    && qRes1 <= Math.Sqrt(12)
    select new { qRes1, qRes2 };
```

Comment: there is no keyword or something that do this? so I have to think for and do it manually in case of any object or type the linq working on?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you would expect to skip iterations without specifying what condition to skip iterations on.  It does sound like you're looking for a condition which acts upon the result of past iterations, which is nothing like a `continue`.  If that's what you want, I'd suggest clarifying the question.

Comment: This answer ignores this sentence `so I want to know the way of doing such thing no matter what is the type of object being linqed to!` right?

Comment: @OkayGuy: given the context of this question which deals with integers i.e. numbers this solution works brilliantly. For different types, the conditions would have to be different too. If that answers your doubt

Comment: @Amn integers are just samples, that sentence is the real question in my opinion.He is looking for an expression for that type of action.

Comment: @OkayGuy What type of action?  In a normal `foreach` loop you say `if (x) continue;`  In a LINQ query you would say `where !x`.

Comment: like a new thing without any conditions like Take or skip something.

Comment: The underlying question, other than the LINQ equivalent of `continue` appears to be how to select unique combinations meeting some criteria using LINQ.  Check this question in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479980/select-all-unique-combinations-of-a-single-list-with-no-repeats-using-linq

Answer (score 2):

You could use .Distinct() and create your own IEqualityComparer that compares objects based on what 'equals' means in your case.

So, for your original example:

```
class PairSetEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        public bool Equals(Tuple<int, int> x, Tuple<int, int> y)
        {
            return (x.Item1 == y.Item1 && x.Item2 == y.Item2) ||
                   (x.Item1 == y.Item2 && x.Item2 == y.Item1);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Tuple<int, int> obj)
        {
            return obj.Item1*obj.Item2;
        }
    }
```

And, you use it like this:

```
var queryResult =
            (from qRes1 in queryValues1
            from qRes2 in queryValues2
            where qRes1 * qRes2 == 12
            select new Tuple<int, int>(qRes1, qRes2)).Distinct(new PairSetEqualityComparer());
```