# WPF DataGrid binding with subList

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a Class like below,

```
Public class Module
{
    Public string ModuleName;
    Public string ModuleId;

    Public List<SubModule> SubModules;
}

Public class SubModule
{
    Public string SubModuleName;
Public string SubModuleDesc;
}
```

In my ViewModel, I have List of Modules

```
List <Module> Modules;
```

I am binding Modules to DataGrid,

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Name="ModuleInfoGrid" 
                SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell">
```

And now binding Name and Id of Module to first 2 columns,

For the next 2 columns, I want to bind subModuleName and SubModuleDesc

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:SubModuleName.}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Path=???????,Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:SubModuleDesc.}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Path=???????,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

My requirement is

1. A Module can have n number of subModules,
2. If SubModule is not present only ModuleName and Moduleid will be present and SubModuleName and SubModuleDesc will be empty,
3. If SubModules are
   present there will be n number of Module entries should be shown,

For example

1. Assume there are 2 modules and
2. Module 1 has  4 subModules and
3. Module 2 has no submodules then grid should be like below,

[image]

How to bind subModuleName and subModuleDesc ?

Comment: Have you tried flattening your sub list and autogenerating columns ?

Comment: @Muds : sorry i am new to WPF , how to do flattening ?

Comment: not new to Google :) .. have a look here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428940/how-to-flatten-nested-objects-with-linq-expression

Comment: let me know if you are having issues.

Comment: @Muds: Thanks for providing your inputs. I can understand about flattening from this example. How to bind it with datagrid columns ?