# SelectMany on tuples of { key, values } - obtain key in result?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `{ string Key, IEnumerable<string> Values }` items and want to transform it into a list of `{ string Key, string Value }` items, such that the new list contains `n` items for each `Key`.

I want to use LINQ and had the idea to use `SelectMany`:

```
list.SelectMany(item => item.Values)
```

However, as you can see, I lose the `Key` with that transformation. What's the trick? I guess it should be easy and I am just missing the forest for the trees...

Comment: I guess you need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428940/how-to-flatten-nested-objects-with-linq-expression

Comment: `list.SelectMany(item => item.Values, (item, value) => Tuple.Create(item.Key, value))`

Comment: Yep, forest ... trees ... overloads ... thanks!

Comment: Follow up question: is there a possibility to add a `NULL` tuple for each empty values collection?

Comment: Currently using `item.Values.Concat(new string[]{null})` - doesn't look very "performancy".

Comment: `item.Values.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Thanks SO! Response time is amazing! :-) Readers: note that my "solution" has been always adding null entries, while PetSerAl's solution adds null entries only iff the collection is empty.

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this brain freeze. Adding the answer by @PetSerAl from the comments:

```
list.SelectMany(item => item.Values.DefaultIfEmpty(), (item, value) => Tuple.Create(item.Key, value))
```

Answer (score -2):

Not the compiled code but this may answer your question

`var finalList=list.SelectMany(item => item).Select(final => new{KeyName=item.Key,Coll=item.Values}).ToList();`