# How to flatten nested objects (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, models

I'm doing some work on an old Winforms grid and i have two Models that i am trying to flatten and assign to a DataGridView.

Here are my sample models.

```
public class StockItem
{
     public string StockName { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
     public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The data works in a way that a warehouse must first be created and then assigned to each `StockItem`. A `StockItem` may have all the warehouses or may only have one.

I need to flatten the data so that the grid shows the `StockName` and then all the associated warehouses for the stock item.

Example

```
StockCode1      Warehouse1   Warehouse2   Warehouse3
StockCode2      Warehouse1   Warehouse2   
StockCode2      Warehouse1                Warehouse3
```

I've attempted to do this via a Linq query but can only get a record per StockItem\Warehouse.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428940/how-to-flatten-nested-objects-with-linq-expression

Comment: This is not really flattening, but crosstab / pivoting

Comment: What would the resulting data type be?  Is there a maximum number of possible warehouses that can be associated with a `StockItem`?  I am not familiar with the WinForms `DataGridView` so there may be something I am missing but wouldn't you have to bind it to a collection of strongly typed objects?  It seems that with a variable number of warehouses you could not do that.

Comment: Can you create a piece of code and share how you are constructing the data? But generally speaking you should be able to get the data using LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating a `DataTable` that yon can easily use as a source for the gridview. First add all columns and then for each stock add the warehouses:

```
var warehouseNames = 
    stocks
    .SelectMany(x => x.Warehouses.Select(y => y.WarehouseName)).Distinct();

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("StockCode");

foreach (var name in warehouseNames)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(name);
}

foreach (var stock in stocks)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["StockCode"] = stock.Id;
    foreach (var warehouse in stock.Warehouses)
    {
        row[warehouse.WarehouseName] = warehouse.Id;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

[image: Warehouses]

Answer (score 0):

I do ***not*** recommend it, but you can use [dynamic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) objects to create objects with the shape you want. **Doing this is not a common C# pattern.** This is more common in languages like Python or Javascript.

C# is a strongly typed language and venturing into the world of dynamic objects should *only* be considered when absolutely necessary (think parsing a json blob). I strongly consider you reevaluate what you need to do and approach it from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var availableWarehouses = new [] { 
    new Warehouse { 
        WarehouseName = "Warehouse1",
        Id = 1
    },
    new Warehouse {
        WarehouseName = "Warehouse2",
        Id = 2
    },
    new Warehouse {
        WarehouseName = "Warehouse3",
        Id = 3
    }
};

var stocks = new [] {
    new StockItem {
        StockName = "StockCode1",
        Id = 1,
        Warehouses = new List<Warehouse> { availableWarehouses[0], availableWarehouses[1], availableWarehouses[2] }
    },
    new StockItem {
        StockName = "StockCode2",
        Id = 2,
        Warehouses = new List<Warehouse> { availableWarehouses[0], availableWarehouses[1] }
    },
    new StockItem {
        StockName = "StockCode3",
        Id = 3,
        Warehouses = new List<Warehouse> { availableWarehouses[0], availableWarehouses[2] }
    }
};

var flatten = stocks.Select(item => new {
        StockName = item.StockName,
        WarehousesNames = availableWarehouses.Select(warehouse => item.Warehouses.Contains(warehouse) ? warehouse.WarehouseName : "          ")
            .Aggregate((current, next) => current + "\t" + next)
    });

foreach(var item in flatten) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", item.StockName, item.WarehousesNames);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That should give you what you need:

```
var flattened = stockItems
    .Select(x => new { 
                 StockName = x.StockName, 
                 WarehouseNames = x.Warehouses
                                  .Select(y => y.WarehouseName)
                                  .ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

It will result in a collection of items that contain `StockName` and a list of `WarehouseName` strings. `ToList` added to enumerate the query.

For these sample data:

```
List<StockItem> stockItems = new List<StockItem>
{
    new StockItem
    {
        StockName ="A",
        Id = 1,
        Warehouses = new List<Warehouse>
        {
            new Warehouse { Id = 1, WarehouseName = "x" },
            new Warehouse { Id = 2, WarehouseName = "y" }
        }
    },
    new StockItem
    {
        StockName = "B",
        Id = 2,
        Warehouses = new List<Warehouse>
        {
            new Warehouse { Id = 3, WarehouseName = "z" },
            new Warehouse { Id = 4, WarehouseName = "w" }
        }
    }
};
```

I've got the following result:

[image]