# How to flatten nested objects with null leafs with linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, data-structures

This is a build off of [How to flatten nested objects with linq expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428940/how-to-flatten-nested-objects-with-linq-expression) as I don't have enough reputation to add comments to the discussion.

I'm trying to flatten a tree structure of different types into a single list.

Here is the sample model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}


public class Page
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And sample data:

```
Book: Pro Linq 
{ 
   Chapter 1: Hello Linq 
   {
      Page 1, 
      Page 2, 
      Page 3
   },
   Chapter 2: C# Language enhancements
   {
      Page 4
   },
   Chapter 3: Glossary
   {
   }
}
Book: Pro Linq II
{
}
```

And the desired flat output:

```
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 1"
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 2"
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 3"
"Pro Linq", "C# Language enhancements", "Page 4"
"Pro Linq", "Glossary", null
"Pro Linq II", null, null
```

Is there any way to do this without concat and without processing the collection twice?

Comment: What is the type of the "flat output"?

Comment: string, object, doesn't matter really. I'm just trying to find out how to include those null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a string extension for quoting makes this cleaner:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static string Quoted(this string text) => $"\"{text}\"";
}
```

You need to replace the `null` items with `IEnumerable<>`s that return a single null item like so:

```
var ans = myBooks.SelectMany(b => (b.Chapters == null ? new[] { (Chapter)null } : b.Chapters)
                                      .SelectMany(c => (c?.Pages == null ? new[] { (Page)null } : c.Pages)
                                                           .Select(p => $"{b.Name.Quoted()}, {c?.Name?.Quoted() ?? "null"}, {p?.Name?.Quoted() ?? "null"}")
                                                 )
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there is a cleaner way to accomplish this, but the following will get your desired output based on the input. I used the null coalescing operator to turn nulls into the string `"null"` for ease of printing, you can just as easily leave them null.

```
var result =
from book in books
from chapter in (book?.Chapters?.DefaultIfEmpty(new Chapter()) ?? Enumerable.Repeat<Chapter>(new Chapter(),1))
from page in (chapter?.Pages?.DefaultIfEmpty(new Page()) ?? Enumerable.Repeat<Page>(new Page(),1))
select new {Book = book?.Name ?? "null", Chapter = chapter?.Name ?? "null", Page = page?.Name ?? "null"};
```

And the output

```
Pro Linq, Hello Linq, Page 1
Pro Linq, Hello Linq, Page 2
Pro Linq, Hello Linq, Page 3
Pro Linq, C# Language Enhancements, Page 4
Pro Linq, Glossary, null
Pro Linq II, null, null
```

Additionally, here's the input using the types provided in the question should another user want to experiment without building this out themselves.

```
var books = new List<Book> {
    new Book{
        Name = "Pro Linq",
        Chapters = new List<Chapter>{
            new Chapter {
                Name = "Hello Linq",
                Pages = new List<Page> {
                    new Page {Name = "Page 1"},
                    new Page {Name = "Page 2"},
                    new Page {Name = "Page 3"}
                }
            },
            new Chapter {
                Name = "C# Language Enhancements",
                Pages = new List<Page> {
                    new Page {Name = "Page 4"}
                }
            },
            new Chapter {
                Name = "Glossary"
            }
        }
    },
    new Book {
        Name = "Pro Linq II"
    }
};
```

Comment: providing the input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While not pretty it does produce the desired result.

Using `SelectMany` along with some inline if statements to check for null.

```
var flattenedList = books.SelectMany(book =>
    book.Chapters != null && book.Chapters.Count > 0
     ? book.Chapters.SelectMany(chapter =>
         chapter.Pages != null && chapter.Pages.Count > 0
            ? chapter.Pages.Select(page => string.Join(", ", book.Name, chapter.Name, page.Name))
            : new[] { string.Join(", ", book.Name, chapter.Name, "null") }
    )
    : new[] { string.Join(", ", book.Name, "null", "null") }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer based upon Nkosi's answer with a few very minor tweaks.

- Use of Any()
- No ToList()
- Func added and used to surround text with quotes

The code:

```
Func<string, string> Quote = (s) => "\"" + s + "\"";
var result = books.SelectMany(book =>
    book.Chapters != null && book.Chapters.Any()
     ? book.Chapters.SelectMany(chapter =>
         chapter.Pages != null && chapter.Pages.Any()
            ? chapter.Pages.Select(page => string.Join(", ", Quote(book.Name), Quote(chapter.Name), Quote(page.Name)))
            : new[] { string.Join(", ", Quote(book.Name), Quote(chapter.Name), "null") }
    )
    : new[] { string.Join(", ", Quote(book.Name), "null", "null") }
);
```

This produces:

```
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 1"
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 2"
"Pro Linq", "Hello Linq", "Page 3"
"Pro Linq", "C# Language Enhancements", "Page 4"
"Pro Linq", "Glossary", null
"Pro Linq II", null, null
```