# How to use selectmany in linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, linq

The following is my linq query

```
  var meetingIndividualQuery = meetingsList.SelectMany(o => o.Attendies.Distinct().Where(x => x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId));
```

I have the following class

```
public class Meetings
    {
        public string IndustryCouncil { get; set; }
        public string MeetingType { get; set; }
        public string MeetingDescription { get; set; }
        public string MeetingDate { get; set; }
        public string MeetingHours { get; set; }
        public string MeetingHourlyValue { get; set; }
        public string MeetingTotal { get; set; }
        public List<Individual> Attendies { get; set; }
    }
```

With the above query I am getting the correct list of individaul but how I can I use the same query with the same condition to retrieve the list of Meetings. Can you please provide me any code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "list of meetings"? Every property starting with `Meeting`?

Comment: Meetings What? `MeetingType` or `MeetingDescription` or `MeetingDate` or `MeetingHours` or `MeetingHourlyValue` or `MeetingTotal`? What? Not pretty sure what is asked here?

Comment: I want the List<Meetings> where Meetings is the class with the same condition meetingsList.SelectMany(o => o.Attendies.Distinct().Where(x => x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId))

Comment: Probably there are not many differend companyIds  . Not sure why you used distinct in the first place

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query will return list of meetings, which have at least one attendee with provided company id:

```
var query = meetingsList.Where(m => m.Attendies.Any(i => i.CompanyId == company.CompanyId));
```

You can also apply `Distinct` to Attendies before verifying `Any`