# Why can I not do more than one level of include in my LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 and I have these classes:

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public partial class Topic
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic
{
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to write a LINQ query to populate this class:

```
public class TopicSubTopicSelect
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public string SubTopicName { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have this:

```
        return _subjectsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(s => s.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .Include(s => s.Topics)
            .Include(s => s.Topics.) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(item => new TopicSubTopicSelect(item.TopicId,
                                                    item.SubTopicId,
                                                    item.Topic.Name,
                                                    item.Name))
            .ToList();
```

But it gives me an error on the line where I put <<<<<

What I wanted was to have .Include(s => s.Topics.SubTopics)

However intellisense does not give me this as an option. Any ideas what I am 
doing wrong and how I can modify the LINQ to get the data to fill the TopicSubTopicSelect class

Comment: When asking questions about linq, don't forget to include information about which provider you're using. Linq-to-Objects, entity framework, Linq-to-SQL etc. are all pretty different.

Comment: Sorry it's Entity Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you desired result -

```
.Include(s => s.Topics.SelectMany(t => t.SubTopics))
```

Use `.Select` if `SubTopic` is a `property` but if is a `list`, use `.SelectMany`.

For more clarification refer to [Select Vs SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany).

Comment: Thanks. This works good. So can I confirm I only need the one .Include line?  Also what would the .Select look like? I tried ".Select(item => new TopicSubTopicSelect(item.Topics."  but then have a problem there as I could not get the TopicID?

Comment: I will open up another question regarding the above. Accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
.Include(s => s.Topics.Select(t => t.SubTopics))
```

Use `.Select()` within the `.Include()` to get the desired join.

Making a simple project to test, I received the following:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the difference between Select and SelectMany ?

Comment: Brad - Can you confirm what Rohit said. So should I use SelectMany? Also is one .Include line needed and how can I get the lower level fields to populate my view ?

Comment: @Melina: I believe `.Select` is what you want. http://s21.postimg.org/73gbwoa07/Untitled.png