# Select distinct from property which is List<string>

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a generic list of assets (`List<Asset>`) and one of the assets properties is called Tags which is a list of strings

How would I do a Linq query to get a distinct list of tags.  I tried

```
assetList.Select(a => a.Tags).Distinct()
```

but this returns me an `IEnumerable<List<string>>` instead of an `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was close. You need to use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to select all tags and flatten them into one sequence:

```
assetList.SelectMany(a => a.Tags).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assetList.SelecMany(a => a.Tags).Distinct() . correct it
```

more information about differences [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Answer (score 0):

`Select` only takes objects as they are and `Tags` is a list, so it takes lists. If you need items from these lists, you have to flatten them into one list and then proceed with other operations.

```
assetList.SelectMany(a => a.Tags).Distinct();
```

A nice example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `SelectMany`

```
PetOwner[] petOwners = 
                { new PetOwner { Name="Higa, Sidney", 
                      Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
                  new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi, Ronen", 
                      Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
                  new PetOwner { Name="Price, Vernette", 
                      Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } } };

IEnumerable<string> query1 = petOwners.SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);
```

produces the following list

> Scruffy, Sam, Walker, Sugar, Scratches, Diesel