# C# where select clause

Tags: c#, wpf, json, xaml

I am trying to access element from JSON and binding it to the XAML.
My JSON code:

```
{
   "id":1474976,
   "date":"2014-02-12 20:00:00",
   "dateiso":"2014-02-12T20:00:00+00:00",
   "competition_id":831975,
   "competition":"England Premier League",
   "group":"",
   "home_id":9879,
   "home":"Fulham",
   "homeshort":"Fulham",
   "homepath":"fulham",
   "away_id":8650,
   "away":"Liverpool",
   "awayshort":"Liverpool",
   "awaypath":"liverpool",
   "status":"Finished",
   "halftime":[
      1,
      1
   ],
   "fulltime":[
      2,
      3
   ],
   "extratime":[
      0,
      0
   ],
   "penalties":[
      0,
      0
   ],
   "incidents":[
      {
         "id":2762178,
         "type":"Own Goal",
         "goaltype":"Own goal",
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":30831,
         "player":"Kolo Tour\u00e9",
         "playershort":"K. Tour\u00e9",
         "minute":8
      },
      {
         "id":2762179,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":26782,
         "player":"William Kvist",
         "playershort":"W. Kvist",
         "minute":9
      },
      {
         "id":2762207,
         "type":"Goal",
         "goaltype":"Regular goal",
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":51553,
         "player":"Daniel Sturridge",
         "playershort":"D. Sturridge",
         "minute":41
      },
      {
         "id":2762238,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":31290,
         "player":"Sascha Riether",
         "playershort":"S. Riether",
         "minute":50
      },
      {
         "id":2762248,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":184536,
         "player":"Philippe Coutinho",
         "playershort":"P. Coutinho",
         "minute":56
      },
      {
         "id":2762260,
         "type":"Goal",
         "goaltype":"Regular goal",
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":30352,
         "player":"Kieran Richardson",
         "playershort":"K. Richardson",
         "minute":64
      },
      {
         "id":2762262,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":30352,
         "player":"Kieran Richardson",
         "playershort":"K. Richardson",
         "minute":65
      },
      {
         "id":2762279,
         "type":"Goal",
         "goaltype":"Regular goal",
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":184536,
         "player":"Philippe Coutinho",
         "playershort":"P. Coutinho",
         "minute":72
      },
      {
         "id":2762296,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":156008,
         "player":"Jordan Henderson",
         "playershort":"J. Henderson",
         "minute":77
      },
      {
         "id":2762307,
         "type":"Goal",
         "goaltype":"Penalty",
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":30618,
         "player":"Steven Gerrard",
         "playershort":"S. Gerrard",
         "minute":90
      },
      {
         "id":2762311,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":9879,
         "team":"Fulham",
         "teamshort":"Fulham",
         "teampath":"fulham",
         "player_id":30839,
         "player":"Johnny Heitinga",
         "playershort":"J. Heitinga",
         "minute":90
      },
      {
         "id":2762312,
         "type":"Yellow",
         "goaltype":null,
         "team_id":8650,
         "team":"Liverpool",
         "teamshort":"Liverpool",
         "teampath":"liverpool",
         "player_id":30618,
         "player":"Steven Gerrard",
         "playershort":"S. Gerrard",
         "minute":90
      }
   ]
}
```

My c# code:

```
 GoalsList.ItemsSource = 
         results.Where(x=>x.id==football.Livestring).Select(y=>y.incidents)
           .Select(z=>z.Select(m=>new
                {
                    player=m.player.ToString(),
                   goalminute=m.minute.ToString(),
                })).ToList();
```

Xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="GoalsList">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding player}" Foreground="White">
            <Run Text="{Binding goalminute}" Foreground="White"></Run>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>



public void getId(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
        {
            GoalsList.ItemsSource = results.Where(x => x.id==football.Livestring)
                                           .Select(y => y.incidents)
                                           .Select(z => z.S‌​elect(m => new
                                                   {
                                                       player = m.player,
                                                       goalminute = m.minute,
                                                   })).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Not getting values of player and goalminute. Whats wrong? I tried accessing some values, they are working fine, but when i try to access incidents array it doesnt work.help

Comment: Post `results` code that how it is filled?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that your query is returning some results? (by checking in debug mode)

Comment: Yeah that GoalList.Itemsource query works just fine with some other where clause condition but may be some tree travelling issues with this one.

Comment: you don't use json string downloaded (which is in `e.Result`)??

Comment: yeah thats what i am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a flat list, but you get List of List. Try using `SelectMany` method like this:

```
GoalsList.ItemsSource = results.Where(x => x.id == football.Livestring)
                                       .Select(y => y.incidents)
                                       .SelectMany(z => z.S‌​elect(m => new
                                               {
                                                   player = m.player,
                                                   goalminute = m.minute,
                                               })).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for noticing that. @nachiket - Read on [Select Vs SelectMany](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany).

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you debug (step into) your code?

2) it will be useful if you can first divide you LINQ into several statements, for example:

```
var football = results.Where(x => x.id==football.Livestring);
var incidents = football.Select(y => y.incidents);
var playerGoalMinute = incidents.Select(z => z.S‌​elect(m => new
                                               {
                                                   player = m.player,
                                                   goalminute = m.minute,
                                               });
GoalsList.ItemsSource = playerGoalMinute.ToList();
```

and check whether each variable (or its Count) is as expected.