# select list of related grandchild entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Trying to get an IEnumerable WorkOrderHeader given the following table structure:

```
OrderHeader 1:many OrderDetails
OrderDetail 1:1 WorkOrderHeader
```

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<WorkOrderHeader> GetInProcessWorkOrdersForOrderBy(OrderHeader orderHeader)
{
    var orderDetails = orderHeader.OrderDetails;
    var workOrders= orderDetails.Select(od => od.WorkOrderHeaders.Where(woh => woh.StatusId < (int)WorkOrderStatus.Complete));
    return workOrders;
}
```

This is returning a nested `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<WorkOrderHeader>>`. How do I get just the inner `IEnumerable<WorkOrderHeader>`?

Comment: List of list? `SelectMany()` to flatten it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/

Comment: @Yuck yep...I always forget about the ol' SelectMany(). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for SelectMany

```
var workOrders= orderDetails.SelectMany(od => ...)
```