# How to make list of ICollection

Tags: linq

**Model class:**

```
public class MonthlySalesOrders : BaseNopEntityModel
{

    public ICollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
    private PagedList.IPagedList<MonthlySalesOrders> orderByDateAdded()
    {

        var ord = _orderService.SearchOrders();
        var daylyOrderReport = (from o in ord.AsEnumerable()
                                group o by new { Quarter = ((o.CreatedOnUtc.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)))) } into orGrp
                                select new MonthlySalesOrders
                                {  Categories = (ICollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem>)orGrp.Select(c => c.OrderItems)
                                })

        return daylyOrderReport.ToPagedList(1, 10);
    }
```

From above "controller action" I have used linq query to select orderlist from "orGrp group", and into "Model class" I have declared a `public ICollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem> Categories { get; set; }`, so when I build and ran the above code it displays following error messages.

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.Order,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem]'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.Order,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem]'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 2374:            var daylyOrderReport = (from o in ord.AsEnumerable()
>   Line 2375:                                    group o by new { Quarter = ((o.CreatedOnUtc.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)))) } into orGrp
>   Line 2376:                                    select new MonthlySalesOrders
>   Line 2377:                                    {
>   Line 2378:                                        Year = orGrp.First().CreatedOnUtc.Year.ToString(),

and I want get category list from three level nested reference from `orGrp` like `Categories =(ICollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem>)  orGrp.Select(gb => gb.OrderItems.Select(s => s.Product.ProductManufacturers))`
so please help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) function which returns an [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, it looks like `c.OrderItems` is an enumerable of items, not a single item. If this is the case then you'll want to flatten list returned with [SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany).

```
orGrp.SelectMany(c => c.OrderItems).ToList()
```