# Linq SelectMany error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am new to LINQ lambda expression and i have been stuck for a while regarding the below issue.
I want to perform a left outer join and want to select the left table not the right table but the below query gives me error when I select the Left table

The "query" is an IQueryable and also the "model2"

[image]

```
 var model = query.GroupJoin(model2,
                    o => o.plu,
                    m => m.plu,
                    (o, m) => new
                    {
                        SmartCoupon = o,
                        Product = m.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    })
                    .SelectMany
                    (
                        a => a.SmartCoupon
                    );
```

Below is the Correct query with the right table but i need the left table

```
var model = query.GroupJoin(model2,
                    o => o.plu,
                    m => m.plu,
                    (o, m) => new
                    {
                        SmartCoupon = o,
                        Product = m.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    })
                    .SelectMany
                    (
                        a => a.Product 
                    );
```

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

It is used to flatten List inside another List you need `Select()` here:

```
.Select(a => a.SmartCoupon);
```

Suppose you have ``` List<List<string>>`` and you want all string in a ```List`, then you need to use`SelectMany()`.

### For Example:

```
var nameList = new List<List<string>>()
                            {
                                new List<string>
                                    {
                                       "Matt","Adam","John","Peter","Owen"
                                    },
                                new List<string>
                                    { 
                                       "Tim","Jim","Andy","Fred","Todd"
                                    }
                            };
```

now use `SelectMany()` to get a single `IEnumerable<string>`, if you use Select it will return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`:

```
var namesInSingleList = nameList.SelectMany(x => x);
```

you can see [difference between Select and SelectMany in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Comment: Okay . But If i replace select will I have a left join ? Because I looked into the output sql query in the sql pro filer and there is no left outer join with product table in the output query

Comment: ``Select`` and ``SelectMany`` have nothing to do with left join

Comment: okay How about I want to Merge two tables record in the selectmany and return them as one list. like this cross join
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13035259/1202610

Comment: Trying to understand. working I am stuck on this for too long now. wait. can we chat on stackoverflow. please

Comment: Okay when I do This 
 var model = query.GroupJoin(model2,
                        o => o.plu,
                        m => m.plu,
                        (o, m) => new
                        {
                            SmartCoupon = o,
                            Product = m.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        });
I get the this result in the query 
"select * from (select * from SmartCoupon left join Product)" which is right but I am unable to get the records of the outer most select statment