# Array of classes that contains array to jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class that encapsulates an array like this :

```
public class Data
{
    public double[] buffer  = new double[10];
}
```

Then I have an array of `Data` objects:

```
Data[] arrayOfData  = new Data[10];
```

What is the most efficient way to get a jagged array `double[][]` from all the buffer in all `arrayOfData` objects ?

Comment: In terms of which efficiency? Performance? Memory? Ease of writing the code?

Comment: Define efficient: easy to write? Easy to read? Fast to run? If the last one: how fast? What are you bottlenecking on?

Answer (score 0):

Linq would be one option

```
double[][] result = arrayOfData.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.buffer).ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**: added a null-check because `Data` can be `null` but `double` not

Comment: Isn't [`SelectMany`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany) available to not have multiple `Select` calls?

Comment: @UweKeim I think that would only help if you were going for a `double[]` rather than a `double[][]`. But the nested `Select` does look unnecessary, since there's no change being done.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `for` loop here. It's just two lines of code :

```
Data[] arrayOfData  = new Data[10];
double[][] allBuffers = new double[arrayOfData.Length][];

for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfData.Length; i++) allBuffers[i] = arrayOfData[i].buffer;
```

Or if you prefer to do it with LINQ:

```
double[][] allBuffers = arrayOfData.Select(a => a.buffer).ToArray();
```

The problem with this line of code however is that LINQ has set of extension methods for interface `IEnumerable<T>` and therefore it uses `foreach` loop that is considerably slower than `for` and is widely used only to iterate through collections and not arrays.

Comment: the linq part is c&p from my answer -1

Comment: @fubo no fubo, it isn't. You've used two `.Select()` methods in your answer and only later you've edited your answer... But this doesn't matter  because this question is not accurate anyway...