# How to iterate a list returned from a Dictionary using Linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, list, ienumerable

I need to iterate a list returned from a Dictionary by Linq. 
But, if I use `ToList()`, it becomes a List of a List.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<double, double>, List<Tuple<double, double>>> dict = new   Dictionary<Tuple<double,double>,List<Tuple<double,double>>>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int x =0; x < 3 ; ++x)
        {
             double a = rnd.NextDouble()*100;
             double b = rnd.NextDouble()*100;
             double c = Math.Ceiling(rnd.NextDouble()*100);
             double d = Math.Ceiling(rnd.NextDouble()*100);
             Tuple<double, double> tp = new Tuple<double, double>(c, d);
             List<Tuple<double, double>> ll = new List<Tuple<double,double>>();
             ll.Add(tp);
             c = Math.Ceiling(rnd.NextDouble() * 100);
             d = Math.Ceiling(rnd.NextDouble() * 100);
             tp = new Tuple<double, double>(c, d);
             ll.Add(tp);
             dict.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(a, b), ll);
        }

        var t = dict.Where(x => x.Key.Item1 == 50 || Math.Abs(x.Key.Item1 - 80) < 20).Select(x => x.Value);
        // if I used
        var t = dict.Where(x => x.Key.Item1 == 50 || Math.Abs(x.Key.Item1 - 80) < 20).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        // it became a list of list.
        foreach(var u in t)
        // here I cannot use u.item1 why? 
        // t is an Ienumerable of list<Tuple<double, double>>
        // if I used foreach(var u in t.Tolist())
        // it became a list of list.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Not too sure on your data structure but can you do this:

```
var t = dict.Where(x => x.Key.Item1 == 50 || Math.Abs(x.Key.Item1 - 80) < 20)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Ultimately if you have collections nested, `SelectMany` basically collapses many collections into one. So in the case of your collections per Dictionary, it flattens them into one so instead of returning an `IEnumerable` for each element, it returns them as one nice collection :)

The example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) is pretty nice, and explains how a collection of Objects, each with their own `List<T>`. So basically when we do the `SelectMany` it flattens the numerous collections into one which we can `Select` from.

**Additional Resources**

[Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

[SelectMany on DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/selectmany)