# Convert list of elements with list to single list using lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have list of households and each households includes a list of residents. I want to have a function that returns a list of all residents of all households.

What I have so far:

```
public List<Resident> Residents() {
    var list = new List<Resident>();
    Households.ForEach(x => list.AddRange(x.Residents));
    return list;
}
```

Is it possible to shorten this with a lambda? Something like this:

```
public List<Resident> Residents => { ??? }
```

I know if Households were a list of lists I could use `SelectMany`, however it is not.

**EDIT1:**

To make it clear, Household is a class, not a container.

**EDIT2:**

I tried the following

```
public List<Resident> Residents => Households.SelectMany(h => h.Residents);
```

However this gives me the error:

> error CS1061: 'List< Household>' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and no extension method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type 'List< Household>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**EDIT3:**

Sorry, I thought I was clear. Household is a class which has a list of residents, like this:

```
class Household {
    public List<Resident> Residents { get; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your remark about SelectMany. Why can't you do `Households.SelectMany(x => x.Residents)`?

Comment: What type is Hoseholds if not a list? Can't you do `.ToList()` on it before? Or have you forgot to add a `using` statement and that's why you don't see the `SelectMany`?

Comment: As @KooKiz noted, from your code it looks like you can simply do SelectMany.

Comment: This definitely *looks* like a list of lists and therefore SelectMany should work. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Comment: You start by saying: "I have list of households and each households has a list of residents". But then you say it is not a list of lists. `SelectMany` doesn't require lists anyway; it just requires `IEnumerable`

Comment: Show the definition of this class as we can´t know how to transform an instance of it to a list or any other `IEnumerable`..

Comment: Your edit has made this totally unclear - You say `Households` is a "class, not a container" - what does that mean exactly?

Comment: This makes no sense. It sounds like you have 1 instance of 'HouseHold', which has a list of Residents. That will contain all your residents so nothing needs to be done. On the other hand it's more likely you have a LIST of 'HouseHold' and each of those list items contains a list of Residents. If that's the case its a list of lists scenario.

Comment: Well err...no, it won't contain a definition for 'SeletMany', but it should have 1 for 'SelectMany'.

Comment: You probably just forgot to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference` - well... are you?

Comment: @Dennis_E: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in C# 6.0:

```
public List<Resident> Residents => Households.SelectMany(x => x.Residents).ToList();
```

You need to make sure that you have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code to get the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods - which includes `SelectMany`.

Comment: This is the only answer that mentioned `using System.Linq` in their answer, so I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be shortened to

```
var residents = Households.SelectMany(x => x.Residents).ToList();
```

`residents` will then be a `IEnumerable<Resident>` ( or whatever type `Residents` is, I've assumed its a type called `Resident`).

You can tag `.ToList()` on the end if you actually need a `List<Resident>`.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you are using System.Linq

`using System.Linq;`

`Households.SelectMany(x => x.Residents)` should work no matter if Residents is an array or a List<>

Answer (score 1):

The following is the shortest I think:

```
public List<Resident> Residents() 
{
   return Households.SelectMany(x => x.Residents).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You dont need the `AddRange`, and actually that wont compile as `list` does not exist in your code.

Comment: Yep just realized that I didn't pull that out