# How get all object from List using linq to object?

Tags: c#, linq

I need make simple "linq" request. It should be "linq to objects" request.
So, I have `List<G> glist` and I want to get all of GW objects from this list.  I want to see it in style like `model.Select<G>( ... ).Where( ... ) ...`

```
public class G : IEntity, ICloneable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<GW> GWs { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class GW: IEntity, ICloneable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual G G{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must write your table like this : tabe1(Id,columnName,...)  and table2(Id,columnName,...)

Comment: If list isn't database table.so write type of g and gw and their members

Comment: Show the code you have written so far. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all gw object like below:

```
List<GW> ListOfGW=(from g in glist let lgw=g.GWs from gw in lgw select gw ).ToList();
```

Comment: `let lgw=g.GWs` is redundant.

Comment: Alternative way is using SelectMany, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany. Thanks you anyway.