# How to keep initializer list order within Select and/or SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

I hope this is not a duplicate but I wasn't able to find an answer on this.
It either seems to be an undesired behavior or missing knowledge on my part.

I have a list of platform and configuration objects. Both contains a member string CodeName in it.
The list of CodeNames look like this:

```
dbContext.Platforms.Select(x => x.CodeName) => {"test", "PC", "Nintendo"}
dbContext.Configurations.Select(x => x.CodeName) => {"debug", "release"}
```

They are obtained from a MySQL database hence the dbContext object.

Here is a simple code that I was to translate in LINQ because 2 foreach are things of the past:

```
var choiceList = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (Platform platform in dbContext.Platforms.ToList())
{
    foreach (Configuration configuration in dbContext.Configurations.ToList())
    {
        choiceList.Add(new List<string>() { platform.CodeName, configuration.CodeName });
    }
}
```

This code gives my exactly what I want, keeping the platform name first which looks like :

```
var results = new List<List<string>>() {
{"test", "debug"},
{"test", "release"},
{"PC", "debug"}
{"PC", "release"}
{"Nintendo", "debug"}
{"Nintendo", "release"}};
```

But if I translate that to this, my list contains item in a different order:

```
var choiceList = dbContext.Platforms.SelectMany(p => dbContext.Configurations.Select(t => new List<string>() { p.CodeName, t.CodeName })).ToList();
```

I will end up with this, where the platform name isn't always first, which is not what is desired:

```
var results = new List<List<string>>() {
{"debug", "test"},
{"release", "test"},
{"debug", "PC"}
{"PC", "release"}
{"debug", "Nintendo"}
{"Nintendo", "release"}};
```

My question is, is it possible to obtain the desired result using LINQ?

Let me know if I'm not clear or my question lacks certain details.
Thanks

**EDIT**: So Ivan found the explanation and I modified my code in consequence.
In fact, only the Enumerable in front of the SelectMany needed the .ToList().
I should also have mentioned that I was stuck with the need of a List>.

Thanks everyone for the fast input, this was really appreciated.

Comment: What if you project to a strong type (`new { Platform = ..., Configuration = ...}` instead of a list of strings? And can you post the SQL that's generated?  It seems very odd that the order would be inconsistent.

Comment: @DStanley What ordered structure would you expect the code to be generated to in SQL?  I'd expect it to create a new bag with those two elements, as that's pretty much the only collection SQL really uses, and it's inherently unordered unless explicitly ordered.

Comment: try your 2 foreach loops without the ToList at end, you will see the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
var choiceList = dbContext.Platforms.SelectMany(p => dbContext.Configurations.Select(t => new List<string>() { p.CodeName, t.CodeName })).ToList();
```

it's really translated to some SQL query where the order of the returned records in not defined as soon as you don't use `ORDER BY`.

To get the same results as your nested loops, execute and materialize both queries, and then do `SelectMany` in memory:

```
var platforms = dbContext.Platforms.ToList();
var configurations = dbContext.Configurations.ToList();
var choiceList = platforms.SelectMany(p => configurations,
    (p, c) => new List<string>() { p.CodeName, c.CodeName })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think the 2 foreach loops that the OP has, seem to be working because of the ToList he has there.

Comment: @sachin Indeed.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah I remember reading something about this elsewhere. I never thought it could apply in my case because of my list of strings. So I just did a couple of tests and you are completely right. In fact, if we want to be precise, only the Enumerable in front of the SelectMany needs the ToList.

Comment: @christ.s Actually the outer query (`platforms`) could be just `AsEnumerable()`, but the inner query (`configurations`) really needs `ToList` and store to a variable in advance, otherwise it will execute the db query for each outer record, which makes no sense (and the performance will suffer).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than projecting it out to an array, project it out two a new object with two fields (potentially an anonymous object) and then, if you need it, project that into a two element array *after you have retrieved the objects from the database*, if you really do need these values in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var platforms= dbContext.Platforms.Select(x=>x.CodeName);
var configurations=dbContext.Configurations.Select(x=>x.CodeName);

var mix=platforms.SelectMany(num => configurations, (n, a) => new { n, a });
```

If you want to learn more in detail- [Difference between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted and I have edited my question accordingly. But it explains the anonymous type state in other comments. Could be really interesting in other cases, tho. Thanks.