# LINQ C# include nested entities

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq

I got following structure:

Class A has a member: `List<ClassB>`

Class B has a member: `List<ClassC>`

Who is it possible to get for one specific object of class A one specific object of `List<B>` and all of it's objects in `List<ClassC>`?

In a other way: How can I get the `List<ClassC>` for a specific `ClassB`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Comment: Are you using EF and are those classes entities of your model? How do you know which `ClassB` object you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

_db.ClassA.Include(b => b.ClassB).ThenInclude(c => c.ClassC);

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var a_list = new List<A>();
var c_list = a_list.First(a => [your criteria here])
                   .b_list
                   .First(b => [your criteria here])
                   .c_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ( to avoid any exceptions)

```
 ClassA classAItem = yourClassAList.FirstOrDefault({your A condition})

    if(classAItem != null)
    {
      ClassB  classBItem = classAItem.yourClassBList.FirstOrDefault({your B condition});

      if(classBItem != null)
      {
        List<ClassC> classCItem = classBItem.yourClassCList);
      }
}
```