# How to get values into list from nested concurrent dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have a nested concurrent dictionary as given below:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentDictionary<string,<Class Object>>>
```

I want to get all objects (values of inner dictionary) into list for further processing without knowing any key.

I tried below two solutions but it does not work for me,

1. outer `dictionary.Values.Select(x=> x.Values)`
2. `foreach` loop

The problem with first solution is that it won't give only objects and second solution is time consuming.

Comment: Could you [edit] and show your `foreach` loop to see why it is time-consuming?

Comment: Use `SelectMany` instead of just `Select`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Answer (score 1):

If you run `dictionary.Values.Select(x=> x.Values)` you would not get a list of object values from the inner dictionaries; you will get a *list of lists* of object values.

To "flatten" that list, use `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (var inner  in dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x=> x.Values)) {
    ...
}
```