# Find all items in all sublist in

Tags: c#, list, linq, sublist

I've an object list with a property that is sublist (object list)

```
public class Class2
{
    public String Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public String ItemA { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> Classes2 { get; set; }
}

List<Class1> classes1 = new List<Class1> ();
```

I would like to find all existing Class2.Item1 in classes1.
Is it possible in linq c# ?
thks

Comment: Maybe with [`SelectMany`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/958949/107625)?

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez."

Comment: sorry, what does that mean "gimme teh codez"  (I'm french and don't anderstand) thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All distinct? However, you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var allDistinctItem1 = classes1.SelectMany(x => x.Classes2.Select(y => y.Item1)).Distinct();
```