# Querying a nested list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I am a beginner learning linq. How to query a list object using linq

```
var dbUserSettings = new List<UserSetting> {  
    new UserSetting { 
        UserId = "abcxyz@123", 
        Applications = new List<Application> { 
            new Application { 
                ApplicationID = "application123", 
                ApplicationName = "ProtocolArchiving", 
                Settings = new List<Setting> { 
                    new Setting { 
                        SettingId = "setting123", 
                        SettingKey = "RefreshInterval", 
                        SettingValue = "20", 
                        IsActive = "true", 
                        UpdatedOn = "2017-06-22", 
                        SettingLabel = "PageRefresh" } } } } },

    new UserSetting { 
        UserId = "abcxyz@345", 
        Applications = new List<Application> { 
            new Application { 
                ApplicationID = "application345", 
                ApplicationName = "ProtocolArchiving", 
                Settings = new List<Setting> { 
                    new Setting { 
                    SettingId = "setting456", 
                        SettingKey = "UploadSetting", 
                        SettingValue = "20", 
                        IsActive = "true", 
                        UpdatedOn = "2017-06-22", 
                        SettingLabel = "Upload" } } } } },
    new UserSetting { 
        UserId = "abcxyz@567", 
        Applications = new List<Application> { 
            new Application { 
                ApplicationID = "application678", 
                ApplicationName = "ProtocolArchiving", 
                Settings = new List<Setting> { 
                    new Setting { 
                        SettingId = "setting789", 
                        SettingKey = "DownloadSetting", 
                        SettingValue = "20", 
                        IsActive = "true", 
                        UpdatedOn = "2017-06-22", 
                        SettingLabel = "Download" } } } } }
     };

 var response = dbUserSettings.Where(e => e.UserId == userID)
                   .Select(dbsetting => new UserSettingViewModel
                   {
                       SettingKey = dbsetting.Applications.Single<Setting>(s=> s == )

                   })
                   .ToArray();
```

I am querying for settingkey which matches with my userID.

Edit:

Missed couple of things to mention. I have tried few things here

```
SettingKey = dbsetting.Applications.FirstOrDefault().Select(sk => sk.Settings.FirstOrDefault()?.SettingKey);
```

The error is as below[image]

My application class looks like this.

```
public class Application
{
    public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public List<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `I am querying for settingkey which matches with my userID.` ok good for you, what's actually the question?

Comment: And what´s your problem? Any unexpected results? Errors? Please be more specific on what you´re trying to do.

Comment: SettingKey = dbsetting.Applications.FirstOrDefault()?.Select(sk => sk.Settings.FirstOrDefault()?.SettingKey)

Comment: I think select many is the thing you re looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Comment: @LaurentLequenne That won´t even compile, as `FirstOrDefault` returns an instance of `Application` which has no `Select`.

Comment: please add the Error/Exception as plain text and not as screenshot

Comment: 'dbsetting.Applications.FirstOrDefault()?.Settings.FirstOrDefault()?.SettingKey' should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you´re just interested in the one and only `Application` for every `UserSetting` I suppose you need this:

```
var response = dbUserSettings.Where(e => e.UserId == userID)
    .Select(dbsetting => new UserSettingViewModel
    {
         SettingKey = dbsetting.Applications.FirstOrDefault()?.Settings.FirstOrDefault()?.SettingKey
    };
```

This will just return the very first (and probably only) `Setting` within the very first (and propbably also only) `Application` within every `UserSetting`. If any of the lists in between in empty (either `Applications` or `Settings`) the `SettingKey` will be `null`.