# Linq Query sub-selection issue

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

The objects are WPF specific, but same thing...

```
        var v = Style.Triggers.Where(x => x is EventTrigger)
                              .Cast<EventTrigger>()
                              .Select(x => x.Actions);
```

At this point, I get 3 TriggerActionCollections which is correct. What I want to do next is select the items *within* each collection that are "is BeginStoryboard". I can't seem to work out how to select the items within Actions (the TriggerActionsCollection).

I was thinking something like this:

```
        var v = Style.Triggers.Where(x => x is EventTrigger)
                              .Cast<EventTrigger>()
                              .Select(x => x.Actions.Select(y => y).Where(y => y is BeginStoryboard));
```

But that isn't working. Any help guys?

For those non-wpf folks. Yes, there are 3 TriggerActionCollections and in one of those there is a BeginStoryBoard object. But for arguments sake I want EVERY BeginStoryBoard object flattened out.

Comment: OfType<BeginStoryBoard>()

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
var v = Style.Triggers.Where(x => x is EventTrigger)
                              .Cast<EventTrigger>()
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Actions)
                              .Where(...)
```

[SelectMany instead of Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany) returns single collection instead of collection of collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = Style.Triggers
             .OfType<EventTrigger>()
             .SelectMany(x => x.Actions)
             .OfType<BeginStoryboard>();
```

Comment: Reviewer here: I guess there's little point in telling you that one-line answers should n...